# What is the difference between `import {history}` and `import history`?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in React, what is the difference between these two:

```
import {history} from '../../app/setup.js';

import history from '../../app/setup.js';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in reactjs, when should I add brackets when import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the package's export format. If `setup.js` sets a `default` export, like

```
// setup.js
export default history
```

Then `import history from …` would pick it up. This syntax will assign the entire export from `setup.js` to `history` in your current module.

If the export is like this:

```
// setup.js
export { history }
```

Then `import {history} from …` would pick it up. This syntax is looking for a `.history` property in the module exported from `setup.js`.