# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this kryptic error from react when I try to import a component. The error message I'm receiving is below. Not sure how to debug this one, any help is appreciated.

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.

--- my index.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers/reducer'

let store = createStore(reducer)

import App from './components/App'

ReactDOM.render(<App store={store}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

-- my app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { incrementCount } from '../actions/actionsOne'
import  CountWidgetContainer   from '../containers/CountWidgetContainer'

export default class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
       <CountWidgetContainer store={this.props.store} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

-- container component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { INCREMENT_COUNTER } from '../actions/actionsOne'
import  CountWidget  from '../Components/CountWidget'

export default class CountWidgetContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
     super(props)
      this.state = {
       count: props.store.getState()
      };
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.store.subscribe(this.handleChange)
   }

   handleChange() {
      this.setState({
        count: this.props.store.getState()
      })
   }

  handleClick() {
   let action = incrementCount()
    this.props.store.dispatch(action)
    console.log('action: ', action);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <CountWidget count={this.state.count} handleClick={this.state.handleClick} />
      ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in reactjs, when should I add brackets when import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import)

Comment: As a side note, you can try [MobX](https://youtu.be/_q50BXqkAfI) rather than Redux. You may like it

Comment: I am thinking about rolling back the edit because you have removed an obvious bug that would make the question a duplicate. Is the error message still the same?

Answer (score 2):

`import { CountWidgetContainer }  from '../containers/CountWidgetContainer'`

In this component You use export default so, You don't need to use curly bracers.

Just `import CountWidgetContainer  from '../containers/CountWidgetContainer'`;

And check component `CountWidget` export, if it's default You shouldn't use curly bracers in `Container` too.

Comment: thats what I though as well. When I remove the curly braces it has the same error still

Comment: What about `CountWidget` export and import?

Comment: @Jimi you are using `redux`, so you need to use `connect`, you don't need to pass the `store` to each component in the `props`. check this for more details: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

Comment: @Andrew, I removed those as well. I still get the same error. Seems really hard to debug.

Comment: @MayankShukla, I'm new to react, open to suggestions.

Comment: @Jimi check the doc, it will explain everything in details how to use connect component with store: http://redux.js.org/ and this also: https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3