# Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'route'" using export default es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Below is my working component

```
const Countdown = () => {
    return(
        <p>Countdown.jsx</p>
    )
}

module.exports = Countdown //working
```

But when I replace `module.exports = Countdown` with `export default Countdown` I got error of `Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'route'`? I have babel and other es6 feature is working.

The way I use my Countdown component like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <Route path="countdown" component={Countdown} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in reactjs, when should I add brackets when import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're *importing* the component. `module.exports = Component` is *not* the same as `export default Component`. When you do `export default`, you create a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports) with the name `default`.

In ES modules you can import the default export like so:

```
import Component from './module';
```

In CommonJS modules, however, you have to reference the `default` export explicitly:

```
const Component = require('./module').default;
```

Comment: you're right, I was doing require('Countdown'), ouch I must be consistent, tried import, it worked. Thansk!