# ES6 how to do multiple default exports

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am still getting a hang of react+redux, and ES6. I am trying to implement socketio, and I come across the problem of having to export socketio connect with my redux's connect.

**redux connect**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

**socketio connect**

```
export default socketConnect(App);
```

**Question**
What is the correct syntax to make them work together?

Comment: There's only one default export because when a consumer of your module does an unnamed import, there's only one thing it can be assigned (the default export).  I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with react+redux, but you should probably be using a named export for one of your exports. Here's a [quick import/export guide](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f) and [ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default-exports-one-per-module).

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import/41338672#41338672, you can have only one default export in a file, so you can export the other as a named export

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't have more than one default export.

Instead, use named exports.

```
// moduleName.js    

export const ConnectedUserList = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList)

export const RealTimeApp = socketConnect(App);
```

Require the exports by name.

```
// otherModule.js
import { ConnectedUserList, RealTimeApp } from "./moduleName"
```

Comment: Here, you haven't used export default. so we can write export default in any one function or variable?

Comment: @ChetanNada: yes :)

Answer (score 27):

You can mix default export and named export.

```
export default ConnectedUserList = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList)

export const RealTimeApp = socketConnect(App);
```

And after, you can import your exports :

```
import ConnectedUserList, { RealTimeApp } from "./moduleName"
```

Answer (score 15):

One possibility I've not seen mentioned. You can have only one default export, but what you export can be an object with multiple members:

```
// MyModule.js
const componentA => () => {return <div>Component A</div>;}
const componentB => () => {return <div>Component B</div>;}

export default { componentA, componentB };
```

And then:

```
import MyModule from "./MyModule";

MyModule.componentA();
```

Comment: You're not exporting a multiple, you're exhorting an object containing two members.

Comment: ^exporting* an object containing two members, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

```lisp
export default () => {
    return {export1, export2};
}
```

Comment: I don't see why folks keep asserting this doesn't work, or that it's somehow exporting two objects.

Answer (score 2):

`export default { constOne, constTwo }` and `import data from './data.js'` will do the trick. To access the data in the target file, it would be like so: `{data.constOne}` or `{data.constTwo}`

### Example

Lets say we have the following `data.js` file:

```
const summary = [  
  { label: 'Turned pro', content: '2020' },
  { label: 'Profession', content: 'Engineer' }
]
const reputation = [
  { community: 'Code Review', points: 176 },
  { community: 'Game Development', points: 101 }
]

export default { summary, reputation }
```

One way to **import** and use the data, would be like so:

```
import data from './data.js'

function App(){
  return (
     <div>
        {data.summary.map((el) => <p>{el.label}</p> )}
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary ways to export values with JavaScript: default exports and named exports. But you can use one or both of them in the same file. A file can have no more than one default export, but it can have as many named exports as you like.