# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using `react native` and `redux`, this is my action:

```
import EMPLOYEE_UPDATE from './types';

export const employeeUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return (
    {
      type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
      paylaod: { prop, value }
    }
  );
};
```

but i get this error:

```
Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
```

EDIT:
the types.js file is:

```
export const LOGIN_USER_FAILED = 'loing_user_failed';
export const SHOW_SPINNER = 'show_spinner';
export const EMPLOYEE_UPDATE = 'employee_update';
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with `types` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import `EMPLOYEE_UPDATE` from `types` file like this

```
import { EMPLOYEE_UPDATE } from './types';
```

Comment: @farmcommand2 Redux does not have any idea wheather you are importing it correctly or not. All it knows is that `type` is undefined and thats what it show in error. I think this is the best error redux can give to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the const as a named import rather than a default import since you have exported it as a named const.

```
 import {EMPLOYEE_UPDATE} from './types';
```

See this answer for details on named and default exports:

[in reactjs, when should I add brackets when import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import/41338672#41338672)

Comment: but we can put `()` around anything that is returned via `return` right ??

Comment: any idea why that error meeasge is that much misleading?

Comment: No It isn't misleading. It says that that type property is misleading. meaning your const is not imported correctly which you will see when you look at how it is exported