# React/Redux export default connect() doesn't seem to be connected to Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

[Solved] Check my answers

I'm learning MERN Stack via a youtube playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO6akRGXhx8. I'm stuck when i reached the 28:04 where he forgot to connect his component with 'react-redux'. I followed how he resolve it but well, for some reason mine doesn't seem to be connected. No props was pass by to my ItemModal component. So i spent 3hrs to debug and lastly conclude that i found it weird that only when the js is named ShippingList, will connect() works... When I renamed ShippingList to another name and update the references, it doesn't work anymore... Please refer to below for some of the snippet

I dont think i need to identify a component to the store when creating it.. so im stupefied now..

Was wondering if u guys can replicate it, please find my repo
https://github.com/AmeDin/mern

ShoppingList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export class ShoppingList extends Component {


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    console.log(this.state)
    //const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect()(ShoppingList);
```

ShoppingListOne.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class ShoppingListOne extends Component {


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    console.log(this.state)
    //const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect()(ShoppingListOne);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Screenshot of console.log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPBBs.png

Further testing
ShoppingListOne

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  console.log(dispatch)

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShoppingListOne);
```

ShoppingList

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  console.log(dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShoppingList);
```

No functions seems to be called for ShoppingListOne.
ShoppingList has a function called line26, 3rd row of console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxwRm.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `mapStateToProps` function as first argument to `connect` in order to make these value available to the component connected to redux store
. Connect without any arguments don't do anything except make `dispatch` available as a prop to the connected component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShoppingListOne);
```

and

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShoppingList);
```

Also you need to make sure that you are imported the connected component which is `ShoppingListOne` exported as a default export rather than a named export

You import would look like

```
import ShoppingListOne from './path/to/ShoppingListOne';
```

Comment: Hello, i have perform this test before reaching to the lines below
export default connect()(ShoppingListOne);
export default connect()(ShoppingList);
for further test behaviour. They result in the same way.. im not able to retrieve the state from the store provider in ShoppingListOne, but able to do so in ShoppingList

Comment: @AmeM remove the export keyword before `export class ShoppingListOne extends Component {` and import this component as default import

Comment: Kathri, the issue was with the importing component. I do not know the difference between export class vs without 'export'. With or without the 'export', it will work if i import the component without the curly braces '{}'. I'm reading to find out more and understand about importing with '{}' or without it and also finding out the difference between 'export class' vs 'class'. Please enlighten me about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281

Comment: @AmeM, the connected component is returned as a default export and hence you need to import it as a default import without using `{}`. You can read more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/what-is-use-of-curly-braces-in-es6-import-statement/41338672#41338672

Answer (score 2):

You must pass *mapStateToProps* and *mapDispatchToProps* to **connect**, so that it can create a wrapper which has access to redux store.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShoppingList);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShoppingListOne);
```

Comment: Please refer to my updates, I appended more description, codes and screens to it

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue...

The import statement seems to play its role to the connection..

Error

```
import { ShoppingList } from './components/ShoppingList';
import { ItemModal } from './components/ItemModal';
```

Correct

```
import ShoppingList from './components/ShoppingList';
import ItemModal from './components/ItemModal';
```

Anyone know the differences? Is there a post out there answering it i wonder?

Comment: `import { ShoppingList }` will try to import the property `ShoppingList` from the default export while `import ShoppingList` imports the default export. If, in `ShoppingList.js`, you're doing `export default class ShoppingList` then you would want to import the default export, i.e. `import ShoppingList`