# How to interpret this import statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've come across code like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

What is the difference between that and this:

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
```

I have rarely seen anything outside the curly braces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is use of Curly Braces in ES6 import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/what-is-use-of-curly-braces-in-es6-import-statement)

Comment: This first imports the default of 'react' as React, the second imports the named export React

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. `React` is probably the default export which should coincide with the other named export.

Comment: @OliverRadini You are correct. I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/753632
I initially thought it had something to do with destructuring.

Comment: @AndroidDev Good ol' Dan Abramov!

Comment: Obligatory MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

This first imports the default of `'react'` as `React`, the second imports the named export `React`