# Export multiple modules ES6 - On import, all modules are within the first one I "peel off"

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am doing the following (both of the exported are objects):

**SlateInfo.js**

`export default {SlateRules, SlateSchema};`

and then in another file

`import {SlateRules, SlateSchema} from 'SlateInfo';`

But what I get is that `SlateRules` is defined as an object containing `SlateRules` and `SlateSchema`

`SlateSchema` is left undefined.

Where am I going wrong/what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Both `SlateRules` and `SlateSchema` should be `undefined` in your example, unless you export `SlateRules` as well somewhere.

Comment: I get the same results if I use `export {SlateRules, SlateSchema}` where both exports end up imported into `SlateRules`

Comment: Are you importing from the wrong module perhaps? If the exports are in your own file, it should be something like `... from './path/to/SlateInfo'`.

Answer (score 4):

`import {SlateRules, SlateSchema} from 'SlateInfo';` is for importing **named exports**. However, `export default {SlateRules, SlateSchema};` is a **default** export, exporting an object with two properties.

If you want named exports then you need to omit the `default`:

```
export {SlateRules, SlateSchema};
```

Or use a *default import* and destructure the object:

```
import SlateInfo from 'SlateInfo';
const {SlateRules, SlateSchema} = SlateInfo;
```

---

[When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196) has a lot of examples showing how named and default exports work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I tried it without default on the export and it results in the same thing.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to put them into consts that way, but since I need these in a variety of files I'd love to avoid that method if possible.

Comment: I also tried `export const SlateRules = {}` and `export const SlateSchema = {}` with the same results if I recall correctly.

Comment: The value of `SlateRules` might already be an object with that properties, we don't know. Also make sure you are using the latest version of Babel. I can only answer based on the information you provide.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean when you say that it might already be an object with those properties. I am using the latest version of babel-core (6.21)

Comment: If you had `var SlateRules = {SlateRules: ..., SlateSchema: ...}; export {SlateRules}`, you'd get the result you are seeing. Otherwise you should not. Without a complete example we can only speculate what else could be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that anywhere, which is why I'm so baffled as to these results.

Comment: I appreciate that fact. Your later points though are on code I have not posted.