# `import {Component} from 'react'` instead of `import * as React ..` in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Sorry for the super newbie vague question, but can I do

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class MyComponent extends Component { ..
```

rather than

```
import * as React from 'react` 

class MyComponent extends React.Component { ..
```

in babel/webpack/typescript/react ish environment?

If not, why's that?

My webpack.config.json is looking like this.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: ['babel-loader', 'source-map-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'happypack/loader?id=ts'
    },

...

plugins: [
  new HappyPack({
    id: 'ts',
    threads: 2,
    loaders: [
      {
        path: 'ts-loader',
        query: { happyPackMode: true }
      }
    ]
  }),

...
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768205/difference-between-import-react-and-import-component-syntax, which is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax

Comment: What happens if you try...?

Comment: it shows the message `TS2686: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

Comment: This is not a duplicate. 

Typescript, by default, does not allow the named imports to be used with many react packages...