# Is explicitly importing Component necessary?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

What is the point of importing React and then importing the Component as well if you can simply access the Component directly from React anyway?

This is what I mean.

You can do:

`import React, {Component} from 'react'`

and then write

`class SomeComponent extends Component`

but you can also do:

`import React from 'react'`

and then write

`class SomeComponent extends React.Component`

What is the difference here? What pain does the first approach really relieves? It seems to me that the second option is much more concise and that the first option is pretty redundant because you have access to `Component` whether or not you import it explicitly.

A much clear analogy would be:

```
import Animals from 'the-world';
```

This would get all animals in the world. Now why would one want to write:

```
import Animals, { Goat } from 'the-world';
```

If `Animals` get all animals in the world, then why import `Goat` separately. I mean it exists already in the `Animals` object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768205/difference-between-import-react-and-import-component-syntax

Comment: @Bergi, The question there asks about the syntax difference not about redundancy. That question is more about default exports and normal member exports. I am asking about the use of importing everything and then in the same line try being specific about what is being imported. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: For instance, the poster there asks why do `import {Component} from 'react' and not do  `import Component from 'react' `. That is not what I am trying to find out. I am trying to find out that if importing React gives you access to its members; Component for example then why the need to write import React, { Component } from react? I mean one could just import React and right there has access to Component without having to explicilty import Component.

Comment: I mentioned the question in the comment just because I thought it might be helpful. For the answer to your question, see the duplicate: In general, named imports are preferred and more concise, it's just that `react` specifically also exports everything on an object redundantly (mostly for backcompat).

Comment: Oh well, but you marked my question as a duplicate even though it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case when individual exports like `Component` are imported, `React` is usually unnecessary. It's a matter of style, for the most part.

`Component` takes less characters to type (also can make use of IDE auto-import), while `React.Component` namespace makes framework imports easier to recognize. They have roughly same footprint in minified output due to how ES modules are transpiled.

`React.Component` style is compatible with cases when React is loaded globally.

`React` namespace also makes it easier to refactor the project to use another React-like framework (Inferno, Preact) and vice versa, because some import names may be different or require additional attention. They can be easier matched with a namespace.

It's always preferable to use

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

instead of

```
import React from 'react';
```

because default import results in entire package being imported, unused properties don't have a chance to be tree-shaken. It's not possible to import both `Component` and `*` on same line because of [syntax limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax) - but usually there is no need for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you `import React from 'react'` you [import an Object](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/React.js#L35) with some properties. You import everything.

When you do `import {Component} from 'react'` you will only import that only one module. By doing this you import far less code to your application (because you only require this part of the library).

However, in real case scenario, your app will require everything anyway so it's up to you how you decide to use it - by destructuring required module or by accessing it on default exported object.

Comment: I get that, but you never import just Component, you have to import React too. So if importing React gets the whole thing, then what is the point of being specific about the next module that you would like to import? For instance importing just Component would cause the program to break because React is out of scope or not imported rather. So one HAS to import React all the time.

Comment: Nothing. In this case it's only a matter of what "looks" better to you.

Comment: If `import animals from 'the-world'` gets all the animals in the world, then why the hack would one want to `import animals, { goat } from 'the-world'`?!?! I mean, goat is within animals. Why the specificity?

Comment: You are right, there is no point, I believe. It's just common that people do that.

Comment: I see, I see. In my opinion, it seems like it's bad practice because it is useless.

Comment: I would say it's useless not a bad practice. In react documentation, they are always using `React.Component` though. However I can see that `import { Component } from 'react'` may benefit some libraries that need just that.

Comment: Hmm, yeah you're right. I was not thinking about that. But wait, is there any library that you know of that completely relies on you having to import just Component? If they want Component, isn't it their job to make sure they import it in their library?

Comment: Yes, it's their job. I was justifying one use case for library authors that would import `Component` alone.

Comment: I hear you. Thanks so much. I like both answers. I prefer the other one though, so will mark it as the accepted.