# 'Redux' is not defined ... as well as ReactRedux and ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working through the React/Redux exercise on FreeCodeCamp.org. After finishing the exercise I want to take it a step farther by implementing it on a local host, and then deploying it to github.

So far, I've used `npx create-react-app {appname}` in node. Replaced, the original app.js file with my own code that I have below and tried to locally host with `npm start` on Node.

When that didn't work I did some googling and found the following command to install redux `npm install redux react-redux redux-thunk --save`. when that didn't work I tried adding the fourth line of my code `import { createStore } from 'redux';`

Currently I am facing the current error

[image]

What can I do to get my app to locally host, so I can then move on to the next step of deploying it to Github?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
// Redux:
const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    message: message
  }
};

const messageReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.message
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(messageReducer);

// React:
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

// Change code below this line
class Presentational extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      messages: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitMessage() {
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      messages: this.state.messages.concat(this.state.input)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Type in a new Message:</h2>
        <input
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
        <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Submit</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.messages.map( (message, idx) => {
              return (
                 <li key={idx}>{message}</li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
// Change code above this line

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {messages: state}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submitNewMessage: (message) => {
      dispatch(addMessage(message))
    }
  }
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Presentational);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppWrapper/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't import them;

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Redux from 'redux';
import ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
```

by the way there is a cleaner way to import what you need. you will need a little refactoring for that:

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider, createStore} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
```

you get the idea, instead of importing the default export, you import selectively and in your code just use the `named import` instead of `default.name` 
(e.g.

`ReactDOM.render(<AppWrapper/>, document.getElementById("root"))` becomes

`render(<AppWrapper/>, document.getElementById("root"))`

Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768270/5953610) for further reading

Comment: Thanks, Iadded those imports into my code, but I still recieve the following message:

./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'react-redux' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactRedux').

How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: the `react-redux` package does not have a default export, which means that line should  probably read `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'`

Comment: @DavidReke check Alex's comment

Comment: Alright I removed ReactRedux and replaced it with { Provider} . From there I recieved an error that declared the const Provider when it was already defined, but I think just removing that line of code where I declared Provider is fine. From there I get a new error message:

"Attempted import error: 'redux' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Redux')."

Comment: @DavidReke check the update; import everything selectively, expect `React`;

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any more errors but my app isn't rendering either. However, I don't think that is included in the scope of this question.