# Importing material ui components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

The code is as follows

```
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
```

vs

```
import { TableRow } from "@mui/material";
```

Which one is better? Will there be any performance difference?

Comment: Is all about named import and default import. You can see the comparison between them from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46913851/11399221

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768270/12572405) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these import statements is purely syntactical, when a module is imported, the entire module is loaded into memory, regardless of whether it has a default export or named exports. So, both `import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow"` and `import { TableRow } from "@mui/material"` would load the same module into memory., The choice between them depends on whether you want to import the default export of a module or a specific named export, the second one is more useful if you are importing more than one module.