# Getting error in mui/material while using grid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2.js 4:14-25 export 'createGrid' (imported as 'createGrid2') was not found in '@mui/system/Unstable_Grid' (module has no exports)

Even though createGrid has export

```
export default function createGrid(options?: {
    createStyledComponent?: typeof defaultCreateStyledComponent;
    useThemeProps?: typeof useThemePropsDefault;
    componentName?: string;
}): OverridableComponent<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>;
export {};
```

And also Unstable_Grid  has export

```
export { default } from './Grid';
export * from './GridProps';
export { default as createGrid } from './createGrid';
export { default as gridClasses } from './gridClasses';

export * from './gridClasses';
```

I don't know why i'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export createGrid from './createGrid';
```

**[image: strong text]**

Also, keep this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768205/difference-between-import-react-and-import-component-syntax) for future reference.