# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export, commonjs

#### Expected

I should be able to export my App component file and import it into my index.js.

#### Results

I get the following error

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

---

#### My index.js

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const App = require('./components/App');
require('./index.css');

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

#### Then in my components/App.js

```
const React = require('react');

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hell World! Wasabi Sauce!
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// module.exports = App;
```

If I uncomment `module.exports = App;` it will work, but I'm trying to use the export syntax. What is driving me nuts is in another project I am doing the exact same thing here and it's working fine :(

Comment: Please don't mix CommonJS modules with ES6 modules. `import`/`export` syntax is reserved for the ES6 modules. When using CommonJS modules, just use `module.exports`.

Comment: I don't want to mix them, but for some reason React is not liking my ES6 export. In this project, I'm using it fine in other projects.

Comment: It might depend on the way your transpiler/bundler handles ES6 modules. 'React.createElement: type is invalid' error is very common when the path is wrong. Could you just `console.log(require('./components/App'))` to see what gets exported?

Comment: I get this `Object {__esModule: true, default: function}` and `default.name` is `App`. My path is correct because the commonJS way, module.exports works.

Comment: Then you should use `const App = require('./components/App').default` in order to get the component (default export).

Comment: Ah I figured it out, my imports were wrong, you are correct... it was a mix problem. I was using `require` instead of `import`. Want to post this answer?

Comment: I will summarize this discussion, provide references and then I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue you have encountered was caused by mixing two different module systems which differ in the way they are [resolved and implemented](http://voidcanvas.com/import-vs-require/). [CommonJS modules](http://requirejs.org) are dynamic and contrary to that [ES6 modules](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#ecmascript-6-modules) are statically analyzable.

Tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) transpile ES6 modules to CommonJS as for now because [native support is not ready yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module). But, there are subtle differences.
By using [default export (`exports default`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export) the transpiler emitted a CommonJS module with `{ default }` property as there can be named and default export alongside in ES6 module. Following example is perfectly valid ES6 module:

```
export default class Test1 { }
export class Test2 { }
```

This would result in `{ default, Test2 }` CommonJS module after transpiling and by using `require` you get that object as a return value.

In order to import ES6 module's default export in CommonJS you must use `require(module).default` syntax by the reasons mentioned above.

---

#### Debugging React.createElement: type is invalid errors

This error is very common when React tries to render a component when there is an issue with the imported module. Most of the time this is caused by missing `export` in the module or issues with the path (relative paths are some kind of a joke) and without proper tooling, this may lead to serious hair pulling.

In this case, React couldn't render generic object `{__esModule: true, default: function}` and just threw an error.
When using `require` there is a possibility to just print out required module to see it's contents which may help to debug the issue.

---

As a side note, please don't mix CommonJS modules with ES6 modules unless you really need. `import`/`export` syntax is reserved for the ES6 modules. When using CommonJS modules, just use `module.exports` and use `require` to import them. In the future, most developers will be using standard module format. Until then, be careful when mixing them together.

Answer (score 13):

## Very often..

...it is as simple as:

```
const MyModule = require('./MyModule');
```

vs

```
const {MyModule} = require('./MyModule');
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, I used "react-data-components" module to get data sorted,filtered and for page navigation.  Previously I imported like ==>import DataTable from 'react-data-components'; then  I got this ERROR. But after adding curly braces It's working fine. ==> import {DataTable} from 'react-data-components'; Nearly I wasted 3 hours time. Again thank you bro

Comment: Please refer this link also::https://reviewdb.io/questions/1527838077232/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-class-function-for-composite-components-but-got-undefined-you-likely-forgot-to-export-your-component-from-the-file-it-s-defined-in-or-you-might-have-mixed-up-default-and-named-imports

Comment: what does wrapping with curly bracket do? I had same issue as OP but { } helped

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue,
i did this trick, worked for me,

you just need to put `export` before `class App`,

```
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

you can also check your router you are using,
I have used this works for me,

```
npm install react-router-dom@next --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into this also...
I was facing this same issue, but only when running my `jest` testing code. I got the same aforementioned error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

If your project happens to be using typescript but you're using `jest` testing (which uses a mix of module systems internally - including CommonJS `require` syntax), you can still get this error testing with `jest` if you use the

```
import React from 'react';
```

syntax in a sub-component instead of the typescript variant:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

It's a weird error & can be hard to catch, since the app may run fine with either import approach, but the `jest` testing of a primary component may fail until the sub-component is updated to use the second react syntax (again, for those using typescript with `jest` testing).

Answer (score 0):

ES6 modules are confusing. If we mix them with NodeJS commonJS module pattern, it will be more confusing ;) ,

I'd recommend use one single style, preferrably ES6 modules if you are working in Frontend code.
I wrote one sample app to understand it better.

https://github.com/Sutikshan/es-bits/tree/master/modules

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue with circular dependencies.

```js
//simplistic example

//a.js
import { foo } from './b.js'
export const bar = foo

//b.js
import { bar } from './a.js'
export const foo = bar
```