# Element type is invalid: expected a string (...) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, gatsby, hot-reload

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>Hi, I am a Car!</h2>;

      }

}

export default Car;
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Car from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am getting the error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `HotExportedComponent`.

I know the import is pointing to the correct class. When I first run locally the desired text shows in the browser "Hi, I am a Car!". Then about half a second later the error pops up. I'm thinking it's something with the hot reload as indicated in the error message. Also I am using Gatsby for this.

[image]

Comment: Have your code works here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/floral-bush-jqebo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. The problem you're facing maybe relate to `hot` function of react-hot-loader

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969578/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-componen. Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby uses a built-in parsing from React, you don't need to import the `ReactDOM` in your `index.js` page like a standalone React application. Just:

```
import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //remove it
import Car from './App.js';

const Index = ()=>{
   return <Car/>
}

export default Index;
```