# React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string but got: object Check the render method of App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, expo

Trying to recreate the Revolut graph from William Candillion's YouTube series of react native tutorials and running into some issues. He developed this example on SDK33 which is no longer available. I keep getting this error message [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWXnh.png)

I am 99% sure it has to do with the import statements, however I cannot figure out where they have gone wrong. I tried looking through the changelogs that expo provides and cannot find the solution. Here is the code from his tutorial

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, Animated, TextInput, }
from 'react-native';
import * as Svg from 'react-native-svg';
import * as path from 'svg-path-properties';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import {
  scaleTime,
  scaleLinear,
  scaleQuantile,
} from 'd3-scale';

const {
  Path, Defs, Stop,
} = Svg;
const d3 = {
  shape,
};

const height = 200;
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const verticalPadding = 5;
const cursorRadius = 10;
const labelWidth = 100;

const data = [
  { x: new Date(2018, 9, 1), y: 0 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 9, 16), y: 0 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 9, 17), y: 200 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 10, 1), y: 200 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 10, 2), y: 300 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 10, 5), y: 300 },
];

const scaleX = scaleTime().domain([new Date(2018, 9, 1), new Date(2018, 10, 5)]).range([0,         width]);
const scaleY = scaleLinear().domain([0, 300]).range([height - verticalPadding, verticalPadding]);
const scaleLabel = scaleQuantile().domain([0, 300]).range([0, 200, 300]);
const line = d3.shape.line()
  .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
  .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
  .curve(d3.shape.curveBasis)(data);
const properties = path.svgPathProperties(line);
const lineLength = properties.getTotalLength();

class App extends Component {
  cursor = React.createRef();

  label = React.createRef();

  state = {
    x: new Animated.Value(0),
  };

  moveCursor(value) {
    const { x, y } = properties.getPointAtLength(lineLength - value);
    this.cursor.current.setNativeProps({ top: y - cursorRadius, left: x - cursorRadius });
    const label = scaleLabel(scaleY.invert(y));
    this.label.current.setNativeProps({ text: `${label} CHF` });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.x.addListener(({ value }) => this.moveCursor(value));
    this.moveCursor(0);
  }

  render() {
    const { x } = this.state;
    const translateX = x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, lineLength],
      outputRange: [width - labelWidth, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Svg {...{ width, height }}>
            <Defs>
              <LinearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
                <Stop stopColor="#CDE3F8" offset="0%"/>
                <Stop stopColor="#eef6fd" offset="80%"/>
                <Stop stopColor="#FEFFFF" offset="100%"/>
              </LinearGradient>
            </Defs>
            <Path d={line} fill="transparent" stroke="#367be2" strokeWidth={5} />
            <Path d={`${line} L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height}`} fill="url(#gradient)" />
            <View ref={this.cursor} style={styles.cursor} />
          </Svg>
              <Animated.View style={[styles.label, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
            <TextInput ref={this.label} />
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.ScrollView
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            contentContainerStyle={{ width: lineLength * 2 }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            bounces={false}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [
                {
                  nativeEvent: {
                    contentOffset: { x },
                  },
                },
              ],
              { useNativeDriver: true },
            )}
            horizontal
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
            );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    marginTop: 60,
    height,
    width,
  },
  cursor: {
    width: cursorRadius * 2,
    height: cursorRadius * 2,
    borderRadius: cursorRadius,
    borderColor: '#367be2',
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  label: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -45,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    width: labelWidth,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I greatly appreciate any and all help thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969578/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-componen)

Comment: That is from 2017 so an even earlier version with different import syntax it looks like

Comment: Have you installed all dependencies with `expo install`?

Comment: Yes I have and I just went down the line and tried again to see if I missed any. No luck yet :/