# Check the render method of `App`. After changing function APP component to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, render, react-router-dom

I'm trying to excecute simple router example in react js. The app.js was a function component earlier i changed it to class component  and performed routing.

I'm attaching the **App.js** code here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About';
import Posts from './Posts';
import Contact from './Contact';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import Nav from './Nav';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Posts</Link>
          <Link to="/About">About Us</Link>
          <Link to="/Contact">Contact Us</Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Posts />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/About">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here the error which is showing is:
[image: Error]

The error is showing in index.js file but i haven't touched it. i'm attaching the **index.js** file here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

This is one of the pages  want to rout. I'm attaching that also  **contact.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav'
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Contact US</h1>
      <p>Contact US page body content</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Contact;
```

Its hard for me to fix the issue referred stack overflow and other web sites i didn't get much idea. Any fix suggestion for this issue is highly helpful for me.

Comment: The file should be named `App.js` not `app.js` (case-sensitive). Also check if it works without `<React.StrictMode>` and `</React.StringMode>` tags.

Comment: the file name is App.js

Comment: Try without importing and calling `reportWebVitals`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969578/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-componen) looks similar to yours. The issue there was mixing two different import styles.

Comment: Can u give the code of posts, about, login maybe unknowingly you are rendering an object.

Comment: @Vitalii i tried it still same error.

Comment: @GayatriDipali   i'm not doing anything with the post i just want to route the second page page. Can you please check my imports.