# React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and react native. I want to use a libary for react native. 
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat
But I got this error :

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check your code at registerRootComponent.js:21.
>       in ExponentRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:128)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:93)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:128)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

Here my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import GiftedChat from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    messages: [],
  };


  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id: 1,
        }}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

I add this lib with :

```
yarn add react-native-gifted-chat
```

I use Expo-XDE to launch my app on a android emulator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the `App` component to render it.

For example:

```js
export default function App() {
```

Comment: sorry it worked for a second then crash again... I added this 'export default App;' at the top

Comment: AppContainer.js:93, what is line of code at this line ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the warning, you likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Just add an export at the bottom of your file

```
App extends React.Component{ ... }
export default App
```