# React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Trying to get react-router-dom and react-redux to play nicely, but getitng the following error in the browser console:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Provider from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './src/reducers/Index';
import Root from './src/views/Root';

let store = createStore(reducer)

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Root />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

reducer (Index.js)

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import Login from './Login';

export default combineReducers({
    Login
})
```

reducer (Login.js)

```
export default function login(state = 'Login', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGINLOADING':
      return state + 1
    case 'LOGINLOADED':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Root.js

```
import React from 'react';
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

class Root extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p> Hello Kitty </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i fixed follow this.

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
```

To

```
 import createStore from 'redux';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom';
```

notice that BrowserRouter is not a default export from `react-router-dom` package.
Hence, you'll need to state it with the curly braces:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```