# React.createElement: type is invalid (map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and trying to create a map element that shows on the app. However I believe I am doing something wrong when I say I am exporting the default class App. This is the error I get "React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: "undefined"" I have my code below.

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
   import { MapView } from 'expo';

   export default class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          region: {
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
           }
         }
       }  
   render() {  
       return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Home Sreen</Text>
          <MapView
            initialRegion={this.state.region}
            showsCompass={true}
            rotateEnabled={false}
            style={{flex: 1}}
         />
       </View>
      );
    }
   }
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
   },
   });
```

Comment: how are you importing and rendering App?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
import { MapView } from 'expo';
```

use

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

Comment: @GMccread If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing export default from class and add it on the last line of your program

```
Export default appname;
```

Comment: That makes no difference (also the capital `E` shouldn't be there)

Comment: Lol.. that's typo.. and i know it