# HTML - styled-components: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Hello I just started using `styled-components` on my project.
My working environment is:

1) `npm version 6.12`

2) `Node.js version 12.13`

3) `VS Code`

After installing `styled-components` from [official documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation):

`sudo npm install --save styled-components`

my project does not compile anymore throwing the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
>   defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`.

**What I have done so far:**

1) As advised by the debugger I double-checked my `Home page` and tried to see if I forgot to `import` the component. However it is correctly imported but still does not work.

2) Always as advised by the debugger I checked if there was a invalid type element. However I think the syntax is correct. To be sure about that I consulted the [official documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started) on how to correctly reference these types of components. Unfortunately it didn't work too.

3) After more research I came across [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string). It seems that it could be due to a not precise reference to the include. However, my project correctly worked/compiled/built until I installed `styled-components`. All the `import/export` I did in the same way.

I am providing the following snippets of code where I have the error:

**StyledHero.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const SimpleButton = styled.button`
    color:red;
    background:green;
`;

export default SimpleButton;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Hero from "../components/Hero"
import Banner from "../components/Banner"

import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import Services from "../components/Services"
import FeaturedVessel from "../components/FeaturedVessels"

import Button from "../components/StyledHero"

export default function Home () {
    return (
      <>
        <Hero hero="defaultHero">
          <Banner title="Vessels" subtitle="Currently Tracked Vessels">
            <Link to="/vessels" className="btn-primary">
                Vessels
            </Link>
          </Banner>
        </Hero>
        <Services />
        <FeaturedVessel />
        <Button>hello</Button>
      </>
    );
}
```

**Additional option I tried:**

As a final note to try to solve the problem I thought that the component I created using `styled-components` is supposed to be exported with the same name, so I also tried to export it with the exact name of the component create inside `StyledHero.js`:

**StyledHero.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const SimpleButton = styled.button`
  color:red;
  background:green;
`;

export default SimpleButton;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Hero from "../components/Hero"
import Banner from "../components/Banner"

import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import Services from "../components/Services"
import FeaturedVessel from "../components/FeaturedVessels"

import SimpleButton from "../components/StyledHero"

export default function Home () {
    return (
      <>
        <Hero hero="defaultHero">
          <Banner title="Vessels" subtitle="Currently Tracked Vessels">
            <Link to="/vessels" className="btn-primary">
                Vessels
            </Link>
          </Banner>
        </Hero>
        <Services />
        <FeaturedVessel />
        <SimpleButton>hello</SimpleButton>
      </>
    );
}
```

If could be useful below my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction and understand what is the problem?

Comment: Does it still complain if you make your Home component return a non-fragment?

Comment: check that every component you are importing in Hero is really a default export and not just an export.

Comment: @JeffMercado, thank you very much for reading the question. No, unfortunately what you are suggesting is not solving the problem.

Comment: @lissitz, thank for reading the question. I double checked everything and I am sure that so far, without `styled-components`, the project runs. I am wondering why after installing it and adding a very simple component caused the problem.