# next.js + expo: You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, expo, next.js

When I try to run `yarn ios`, I get:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MyApp`.
```

But my `App.tsx`, has:

```
class MyApp extends App {


  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ScrollView>
        <FooterBar />
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

So I'm not sure what it's complaining about?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) might help you. The `Component` might be exported incorrectly.

Comment: Can you include the file which renders `MyApp`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its because you need _app.tsx instead of App.tsx? Show me the import statements at the top of your file regardless please

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the component directly from its origin and plugging in your pageProp after. So in example :

```
import {Component} from '../pathOfComponent';
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely are not passing anything in this.props.Component. Javascript is quite tricky, if the element does not exist it will treat it as undefined

Comment: I’m using next.js and somehow that’s handling the Component.