# Jest unable to recognize SVG component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, jestjs

Jest is raising this error on one of my components:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
> composite components) but got: number.
>
> Check the render method of `DoubleTappedClapAnim`. at fn
> (C:\Users\fasta\ExhibitU\components\screen_specific\feed\FeedItem_components\DoubleTappedClapAnim.tsx:11:24)
>
> at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:220:30)
>
> at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:196:5)
>
> at Object.createElementWithValidation [as createElement] (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2215:7)
>
> at Component (components/screen_specific/feed/FeedItem_components/DoubleTappedClapAnim.tsx:26:9)
>
> at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6016:18)
>
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8744:13
>
> at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9966:16)
>
> at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13800:12)

I understand that this error is commonly solved by [fixing imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string).

However the component which I'm running Jest on is importing an SVG (.svg extension picture), which I've only seen one way of importing correctly (& dynamically).

Here's that `DoubleTappedClapAnim.tsx` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Animated, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Cheerfill from "../../../../assets/Icons/clap-fill.svg";
import Cheer from "../../../../assets/Icons/clap.svg";

const DoubleTappedClapAnim = (props) => {
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        ...styles.container,
        opacity: props.fadeAnim,
        transform: [{ translateY: props.slideAnim }],
      }}
    >
      {props.clap ? (
        <Cheerfill
          style={{
            marginTop: props.height,
            ...props.clapContainer,
          }}
          height={props.height / 5}
          width={props.width / 5}
          fill={props.darkModeValue ? "white" : "black"}
        />
      ) : (
        <Cheer
          style={{
            marginTop: props.height,
            ...props.clapContainer,
            transform: [{ rotate: "5deg" }],
          }}
          height={props.height / 5}
          width={props.width / 5}
          fill={props.darkModeValue ? "white" : "black"}
        />
      )}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default DoubleTappedClapAnim;
```

and this is my `DoubleTappedClapAnim.test.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import DoubleTappedClapAnim from "../DoubleTappedClapAnim";

test("matches previous snapshot and renders correctly", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<DoubleTappedClapAnim />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm wondering if anyone has a possible solution or workaround for this?

I've done the typical "transformIgnorePatterns" route, but I think that only goes so far for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by mocking your svg assets, so a string is returned rather than the svg.

```
jest.mock("../../../../assets/Icons/clap-fill.svg", () => 'Cheerfill'))
jest.mock("../../../../assets/Icons/clap-fill.svg", () => 'Cheer'))
```