# ES6 Modules not importing as expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, ecmascript-6

I've been having an issue with importing a react class into a container

My file organization is as follows:

```
├── components
│   ├── Header
│   │   ├── Header.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── index.js
├── containers
│   └── HeaderContainer.js
└── index.js
```

where `components/Header/Header.js` exports with

```
export default class Header extends Component {}
```

`components/Header/index.js` is

```
import Header from './Header';
import './Header.scss';

export default Header;
```

and `components/index.js` is

```
export Header from './Header';
```

and containers/HeaderContainer.js is trying to import with

```
import { Header } from '../components';
```

However, this doesn't work, Header is undefined.

If I use `import * as components from '../components';`,
Header is listed, but using `components.Header` is again undefined.

However, it works perfectly if I instead do

```
import Header from '../components/Header';
```

Can anyone explain why the first two methods don't seem to be working? I've done it before this way, and I cannot figure out what I may have changed (admittedly, part of the reason I'm asking is just to type it out a new way and seeing if it helps)

Additionally, I've been able to use

```
import { Header } from './components';
```

from an index file in the main directory, which worked perfectly. The issue seems to somehow be with `import { Header } from '../components'` only

Comment: wrt babel/webpack, I'm using `presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']` if that helps at all

Comment: try in components/index.js : import "./Header" instead of export

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: @OlivierKrull I tried doing that already, and the exporting all of the other components in a single object, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a cyclical dependency issue. Consider:

1. `components/index.js` starts loading.
2. It sees it needs `containers/HeaderContainer.js`, so it suspends.
3. `containers/HeaderContainer.js` starts loading.
4. It sees it needs `import { Header } from '../components';`, so it suspends.
5. `components/index.js` is already loading from step 1, so this step is a no-op.
6. `containers/HeaderContainer.js` starts running again.
7. Since `components/index.js` is still loading, the imported `Header` is pointing to a variable that hasn't been initialized yet, like if you did

   console.log(Header);
   let Header = ...

Babel's behavior in this situation is to make `Header` `undefined`. In a real native ES6 module environment, it would throw an exception because `Header` wasn't initialized yet.

There are two main options to fix this. Either one should help:

- Import `../components/Header` directly to avoid the already-loading `components/index.js`.
- Reorder your imports so `Header` is already initialized in `components`. e.g.

  ```
  export { HeaderContainer } from './containers/HeaderContainer';
  export { Header } from './Header';
  ```

  to

  ```
  export { Header } from './Header';
  export { HeaderContainer } from './containers/HeaderContainer';
  ```

Comment: Aha! The cyclical dependency thing is definitely it, I've been importing something directly from components which in turn loads containers, which then load components again. Thanks so much for your help, I don't think I'd ever have figured that out. Marked as correct, I'd upvote but...

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of export: `named` and `default`.
Named export should be consumed by using construct like:

`import { Header } from '../components';`

Default on the other hand should be consumed like:

`import Header from '../components';`

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export);

Comment: I'm not sure this applies, right? I'm using default imports in the `components/index.js`, and then exporting to named imports

Comment: Check the syntax of `export` in the link I have provided. You cant write `export Header from './Header';`. My suggestion would be to remove default exports and stick with named ones. It will make your life easier.

Comment: My issue here is that it does seem to work in another file, it only doesn't work inside the containers directory

Answer (score 0):

Because the only thing you can omit from the path is `index.js`

So if you have

```
import Header from '../components/Header';
```

It is the same as

```
import Header from '../components/Header/index.js';
```

But if you type

```
import { Header } from '../components';
```

Interpreter expects that in the file `../components/index.js` or it could be just `../components.js` if `components` is a file and not a folder, it will find a named export

```
export const Header = () => {...}
```

[More about exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: Yeah, I have an index.js file in components which imports things from the subfolders of `components/` and then exports them, which I don't really understand why its not working the way I expected