# Difference between Import { module } from lib and import module from lib/module in Javascript

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am trying to optimize my vendor bundle.js as it has swollen up and i am using the material-ui library.

```
import Card from 'material-ui'; // Very bad as this will import everything
```

Can someone tell me what the difference between the two import statements are in terms of size of js code imported into your app or are they the same.

```
import { Card } from 'material-ui';
import Card from 'material-ui/Card'
```

Comment: Does `import Card from 'material-ui/Card'` actually work?

Comment: Yes both work. You can refer their docs here http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the code for the upcoming v1...

Answer (score 1):

```
import Card from 'material-ui';
```

This will import whatever is being exported using ***default*** in **material-ui** as **Card** defined in the import.

```
import { Card } from 'material-ui';
```

This will import the named export **Card** (assuming Card exists) from **material-ui**.

Please refer to the following stack overflow post for more information.

[When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, they are the same.

The import

```
import { Card } from 'material-ui';
```

corresponds to importing an exported member called `Card` from the root. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/index.js#L7), we see that it looks like this:

```
export Card from './Card';
```

which imports the [default export](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Card/index.js#L9) from `./Card` (which is `material-ui/Card`).

The second import

```
import Card from 'material-ui/Card'
```

imports the default export from `material-ui/Card`, which we just showed is exactly what the first import did.

Therefore, they are the same.

Comment: I don't think they are the same. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `import { Card } from 'material-ui';` will include the whole library in the bundle unless the bundler you are using have support for tree-shaking. material-ui seems to be using es6 modules which can take advantage of that optimization. On the other hand `import Card from 'material-ui/Card'` will only include the Card component along side with its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is in the compiled code. In order to improve the performance, the first option:

```
import Card from 'material-ui/Card'
```

is the best one because it goes directly to the module you are requesting for.

In the second option:

```
export Card from './Card'
```

Babel uses `transform-export-extension` plugin to compile the code so the compiled code is bigger than the first option.