# React-Redux: this.props.AppendCharacter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I searched for answers to this one but didn't see any that matched my problem.  I am trying to build a calculator app using React & Redux and whenever I click on one of the number buttons, I get an error that says "this.props.AppendCharacter is not a function"

Here is my relevant code:

number_button.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import AnswerScreen from '../containers/answer_screen';
import AppendCharacter from '../actions/index';

class NumberButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { button: '' };
        this.clickButton = this.clickButton.bind(this);
    };

    clickButton() {
        this.props.AppendCharacter(this.props.number);
        console.log('clicked on ', this.props.number);
        this.setState({ button: this.props.number });
    }

    render(props) {
        return (
            <div className="number-button general-button" onClick={this.clickButton}>
            {this.props.number}
            </div>
        );
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ AppendCharacter }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NumberButton);
```

actions/index.js

```
export function AppendCharacter(character) {
    return {
        type: APPEND,
        payload: character
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need by changing your `mapDispatchToProps` to:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        AppendCharacter: (character) => dispatch(AppendCharacter(character));
    };
}
```

I'm not familiar with `bindActionCreators`, so someone else may need to weigh in if you need that functionality.

---

Side note: it doesn't look like you need the component state for `button` in your current set up. You may have plans for it, but it's unused in your example.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it, but I got a different error that said "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _index2.default) is not a function"

(Oh, and I am probably going to remove the component state once I get this working -- I changed my design after adding that part.  Thanks for the comment on that.)

Comment: You're close. Sounds like this solved your problem. Now, you need to revisit how you're `import`ing and `export`ing. Sounds like you may have (or not have) a `default` export when you meant to (or didn't mean to). [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/2479481)

Comment: The original `mapDispatchToProps` was ok; `bindActionCreators` wraps action creators in calls to `dispatch()`. I woud suggest, though, that if you don't deeply understand how `dispatch()` works, you should not use `bindActionCreators` because it adds a potentially confusing layer over a concept that many already find confusing when they first start using redux.

Comment: @PirateJohn this might also help with the `default` issue: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/issues/116#issuecomment-264629537

Comment: @skypecakes good to know. I'll have to read up on `bindActionCreators` now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  AnswerScreen,
  AppendCharacter 
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NumberButton);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your code but it still didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but it won't work because it doesn't actually map dispatch to props. `mapDispatchToProps` needs to take a parameter `dispatch` and return functions that call `dispatch` for each action creator. See my answer for an example of one way to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the error.  Someone on a different web site helped me.  The bindActionCreators was working fine, but the problem was that when I import AppendCharacter from ../actions/index, I needed to wrap AppendCharacter in curly braces.  I changed that and now the app works.

Whew!

Thank you everyone for your replies.  I've learned a lot in these last few days!