# Why does pulling a variable sometimes return undefined when doing import in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This works

```
import config from './setup/config'
const {port} = config;
```

This gives port as undefined

```
import config, {port} from './setup/config'
// config.port returns a number but port alone is undefined
```

This is also undefined

```
import {port} from './setup/config'
```

Comment: You should read [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196)

Comment: those two things are completely different. One is syntax for import one for destructuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const {port} = config;
```

is a **destructuring** assignment. It "pulls" out the `port` property from the object in `config`.

```
import {port} from './setup/config'
```

imports the **named export** `port` from the module `./setup/config`.

Your module probably doesn't have a named export `port`. Properties of an object that is exported as *default* export do not magically become named exports!

Make yourself more familiar with ES6 modules by reading

- [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196)
- [MDN - `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [MDN - `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)