# Why and when to use default export over named exports in es6 Modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have referred all the questions in stackoverflow. 
But none of the suggested why and when to use default export.

I just saw that default can be metioned  "When there is only one export in a file"

Any other reason for using default export in es6 modules?

Answer (score 91):

It's somewhat a matter of opinion, but there are some objective aspects to it:

- You can have only one default export in a module, whereas you can have as many named exports as you like.
- If you provide a default export, the programmer using it has to come up with a name for it. This can lead to inconsistency in a codebase, where Mary does

  ```
  import example from "./example";
  ```

  ...but Joe does

  ```
  import ex from "./example";
  ```

  In contrast, with a named export, the programmer doesn't have to think about what to call it unless there's a conflict with another identifier in their module.¹ It's just

  ```
  import { example } from "./example";
  ```
- With a named export, the person importing it has to specify the name of what they're importing. They get a nice early error if they try to import something that doesn't exist.
- If you *consistently* only use named exports, programmers importing from modules in the project don't have to think about whether what they want is the default or a named export.

---

¹ If there *is* a conflict (for instance, you want `example` from two different modules), you can use `as` to rename:

```
import { example as widgetExample } from "./widget/example";
import { example as gadgetExample } from "./gadget/example";
```

Comment: So this answer says that default exports are simply worse than named ones, and should pretty much never be used....

Answer (score 59):

Some differences that might make you choose one over the other:

Named Exports

- Can export multiple values
- MUST use the exported name when importing

Default Exports

- Export a single value
- Can use any name when importing

[This article](https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65) does a nice job of explaining when it would be a good idea to use one over the other.

Comment: Named export doesn't have to use the same name: `import { OriginalName as CustomName } from './file'`.

Comment: You still must use the exported name when importing. But true, you can alias that exported name to something else of your choosing.

Comment: @Ben what? No, you don't need to use the exported name of the default export. It's completely transparent.

Comment: I thought you talk about named default export for some reason.

Comment: thanks for the link. So default export is only a useful transitional refactoring between CommonJS and ES Modules. But in practice it is considered an Anti-pattern

Comment: One major drawback about working with default exports (having worked on large projects) is that complicate thing on a developer experience point of view, i.e while searching for dependencies of those exports. People might call whatever name and that makes it difficult to track.

Comment: *"Named Exports...Can export multiple values..."* That's incorrect, named exports can't do anything default exports can't do (not that I recommend using default exports; I don't). The only technical difference between a default export and a named one is that the default one uses the synthetic name `default`. Other than that, it's syntactic sugar. You can't export "multiple values" regardless of what kind you use (though with either, you can export a container of multiple values, like an array or object).

Answer (score 43):

You should almost always favour named exports, default exports have many downsides

Problems with default exports:

1. Difficult to refactor or ensure consistency since they can be named anything in the codebase other than what its actually called
2. Difficult to analyze by automated tools or provide code intellisense and autocompletion
3. They break tree shaking as instead of importing the single function you want to use you're forcing webpack to import the entire file with whatever other dead code it has leading to bigger bundle sizes
4. You can't export more than a single export per file
5. You lose faster/direct access to imports

checkout these articles for a more detailed explanation:

https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad

https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/

https://rajeshnaroth.medium.com/avoid-es6-default-exports-a24142978a7a

Comment: Do you have any reference to prove that named export is faster than default export? Because that would be great.

Comment: @jave.web its not necessarily that the export itself is faster, its that it allows bundlers like webpack to make use of a feature called tree-shaking see https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ which is a way to eliminate dead code from your project, so using named exports makes tools like webpack able to statically analyse your code and see what you're importing from that file.. named exports however forcefully import the entire file than part of it which breaks tree-shaking. so ofcourse smaller bundle means better rendering performance, less network delay and parsing times.

Comment: @jave.web this is also why alot of libraries recently publish new versions of their libraries with different import syntax to make it more tree-shakable and therefore reducing the bundle sizes allowing consumers to only import the functionalities that they need. for example imports like "material-ui/Button" which internally points to a "Button/index.js" file that only exports the Button component as opposed to a default "material-ui" import pointing to "src/index.js" which imports and exports all components in the library which would lead to a much bigger bundle size.

Comment: Oh, you mean it like that - great explanation, thank you :-) I like it for code maintainability anyways and this is just one more reason to teach others, thank you :-)

Comment: @KhaledOsman - *"They break tree shaking as instead of importing the single function you want to use you're forcing webpack to import the entire file with whatever other dead code it has leading to bigger bundle sizes"* Do you have a citation for that? (Your [first link](https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad) cites an anti-pattern that would have that effect, but you have to adopt the entire anti-pattern, default exports themselves aren't sufficient AFAIK; the other two don't mention tree shaking). The only...

Comment: ...technical difference between a default export and a named one is that the synthetic name `default` is used. The rest is syntactic sugar. What makes you think that breaks tree-shaking? (For the record: I think default exports are a Bad Idea™, but it's just I don't think that particular claim is accurate.) Thanks!

Comment: @KhaledOsman - I figured why make you do the work when I could easily test to see if I was mistaken. :-) I appear to be correct, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/farsightsoftware/7a553ada9fd632fca5ed4c68bf2c4a7b) which (for me) demonstrates tree-shaking despite a default export being used. I think your third bullet point needs to call out the entire anti-pattern, because default exports *on their own* don't defeat tree-shaking. Good point about the anti-pattern though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting, what happens if you remove the "export" keyword from the unused function? I'm wondering if this actually works because unused is not a default export in that case

Comment: @KhaledOsman - It still isn't included (why would it be? nothing uses it). *"I'm wondering if this actually works because unused is not a default export in that case"* I don't know what you mean by that. There can only be one default export in a module, and that module already has one. The point here is that tree-shaking works. I did think of something else to try: Importing the *other* (named) export instead of the default and making sure that the default isn't included in the bundle (since it's not imported). That worked too (the default wasn't included in the bundle).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting, maybe webpack got smarter over the years, or maybe its specifically related to the pattern of exporting one big object as a default export as shown in this article https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad#b78a 

There's also few questions that state the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816190/what-is-the-right-way-for-better-treeshaking-in-webpack

Comment: @KhaledOsman - Sure, if you export one big object, you're defeating tree-shaking. But it's the big single object that's the problem (regardless of whether it's the default export or a named export), not whether you're using a default export. That other answer is linking the same article you linked above. Sadly, the article would appear to be not clear enough about what the real problem is, if people are taking "default exports can't be tree-shaken" from it. :-|

Answer (score 18):

With named exports, one can have multiple named exports per file. Then import the specific exports they want surrounded in braces. The name of imported module has to be the same as the name of the exported module.

```
// imports
// ex. importing a single named export
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";

// ex. importing multiple named exports
import { MyComponent, MyComponent2 } from "./MyComponent";

// ex. giving a named import a different name by using "as":
import { MyComponent2 as MyNewComponent } from "./MyComponent";

// exports from ./MyComponent.js file
export const MyComponent = () => {}
export const MyComponent2 = () => {}
```

You can also alias named imports, assign a new name to a named export as you import it, allowing you to resolve naming collisions, or give the export a more informative name.

```
import MyComponent as MainComponent from "./MyComponent";
```

You can also Import all the named exports onto an object:

```
import * as MainComponents from "./MyComponent";
// use MainComponents.MyComponent and MainComponents.MyComponent2 here
```

One can have only one default export per file. When we import we have to specify a name and import like:

```
// import

import MyDefaultComponent from "./MyDefaultExport";

// export

const MyComponent = () => {}

export default MyComponent;
```

The naming of import is completely independent in default export and we can use any name we like.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):
    *Named exports are useful to export several values. During the import, one will be able to use the same name to refer to the corresponding value.
    Concerning the default export, there is only a single default export per module. A default export can be a function, a class, an object or anything else. This value is to be considered as the “main” exported value since it will be the simplest to import.*

Answer (score 11):

There aren't any definitive rules, but there are some conventions that people use to make it easier to structure or share code.

When there is only one export in the entire file, there is no reason to make it named.
Also, when your module has one main purpose, it could make sense to make that your default export. In those cases you can extra named exports

In react for example, `React` is the default export, since that is often the only part that you need. You don't always `Component`, so that's a named export that you can import when needed.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

In the other cases where one module has multiple equal (or mostly equal) exports, it's better to use named exports

```js
import { blue, red, green } from 'colors';
```

Answer (score 8):

1st Method:-

```
export foo; //so that this can be used in other file

import {foo} from 'abc'; //importing data/fun from module
```

2nd Method:-

```
export default foo;  //used in one file

import foo from 'blah'; //importing data/fun from module
```

3rd Method:-

```
export = foo;

import * as foo from 'blah';
```

The above methods roughly compile to the following syntax below:-

//all export methods

```
exports.foo = foo; //1st method
exports['default'] = foo; //2nd method
module.exports = foo; //3rd method
```

//all import methods

```
var foo = require('abc').foo; //1st method
var foo = require('abc')['default']; //2nd method
var foo = require('abc'); //3rd method
```

For more information, visit to [Default keyword explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export)

**Note**:- There can be only `one` export `default` in `one` file.

So whenever we are exporting only 1 function, then it's better to use `default` keyword while exporting

Answer (score 0):

**EASIEST DEFINITION TO CLEAR CONFUSIONS**

Let us understand the export methods, first, so that we can analyze ourselves when to use what, or why do we do what we do.

Named exports: One or more exports per module. When there are more than one exports in a module, each named export must be restructured while importing. Since there could be either export in the same module and the compiler will not know which one is required unless we mention it.

```html
//Named export , exporting:

export const xyz = () =>{
}

// while importing this
import {xyx} from 'path'
or
const {xyz} = require(path)
```

The braces are just restructuring the export object.

On the other hand , default exports are only one export per module , so they are pretty plain.

```html
//exporting default

const xyz =() >{
};

export default xyz

//Importing
import xyz from 'path'

or

const xyz = require(path)
```

***I hope this was pretty simple to understand, and by now you can understand why you import React modules within braces...***

Answer (score -2):

**Named Export: (export)**

With named exports, one can have multiple named exports per file. Then import the specific exports they want surrounded in braces. The name of imported module has to be the same as the name of the exported module.

// imports

// ex. importing a single named export

import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";

// ex. importing multiple named exports

import { MyComponent, MyComponent2 } from "./MyComponent";

// ex. giving a named import a different name by using "as":

import { MyComponent2 as MyNewComponent } from "./MyComponent";

// exports from ./MyComponent.js file

export const MyComponent = () => {}
export const MyComponent2 = () => {}

**Import all the named exports onto an object:**
// use MainComponents.MyComponent and MainComponents.MyComponent2 here

import * as MainComponents from "./MyComponent";

**Default Export: (export default)**

One can have only one default export per file. When we import we have to specify a name and import like:

// import

import MyDefaultComponent from "./MyDefaultExport";

// export

const MyComponent = () => {}
export default MyComponent;

**Note: The naming of import is completely independent in default export and we can use any name we like.**

[Here's a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281#367962) that explains default and named imports in ES6

Comment: This explains *what* a default export is, not *why* to use it and the use cases of it, as the OP asked