# What is the right way for better TreeShaking in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, tree-shaking

I was wondering, which one of the following two options is the right way for better **Tree Shaking** in **webpack**:

```
import { someFeature } from 'someModule'  // Option 1
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash' // Example 1
```

Or,

```
import someFeature from 'someModule/someFeature' // Option 2
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty' // Example 2
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: The code example you give isn't interchangeable so I don't understand what the question really is here? Are you asking should you use default exports over named? Because there would be no difference in terms of tree-shaking here in this example

Comment: This depends totally on the implementation of `someModule` and of `someModule/someFeature`. Please post them.

Comment: @Bergi What if that module is a third party library say, lodash?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Then it still depends on how they implemented their exports - please post them (but reduce to a minimal example). Regarding lodash specifically, [it has its own problems](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6925) since it doesn't use ES6 exports yet, there are various workarounds (importing from subpackages, using `lodash-es´, using a babel plugin that fixes lodash, ...).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, I think you are asking for the benefits of named exports over default exports for better tree shaking or reducing the bundle size.

For better tree shaking, it is advised to use named export over default exports. According to this [article](https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad),

> Sometimes you can be tempted to export one huge object with many properties as default export. This is an anti-pattern and prohibits proper tree shaking:

So instead of using default export as example 1 use named export as example 2.

**Example 1**

```
// This is default export. Do not use it for better tree shaking
// export.js
 export default {
   propertyA: "A",
   propertyB: "B",
 }
// import.js
import export from './exports';
```

**Example 2**

```
// This is name export. Use it for better tree shaking
// export.js
 export const propertyA = "A";
 export const propertyB = "B";
// import.js
import { propertyA } from './exports';
```

So in the first example it will export both `propertyA` and `propertyB` while in the second it will only export `propertyA` which will reduce the bundle size.

Comment: Hi, @Farhad Thank you for your kind response. Please read the updated question.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Tree shaking mostly depends on the way you export not the way you import it. If you are specific to lodash, then this is a good read https://www.azavea.com/blog/2019/03/07/lessons-on-tree-shaking-lodash/. Let me know if it helps you, then I will update my answer

Comment: *"For better tree shaking, it is advised to use named export over default exports."* Using a default export vs. a named one doesn't make any difference to tree-shaking. What the article you linked to is saying is that exporting **one big object** defeats tree-shaking. But it's the big object, not the form of export, that's the problem. Default exports can be tree-shaken just as well as named exports. (That said: I strongly recommend using named exports, [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103685/157247).) Sadly, you're not the only one to be confused by that article.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if you use option one or two, it will not be possible to "tree shake" unused things from your "someFeature" if that is one huge object or class with many properties and you are using only some of those properties. So the best option would be to chunk your "someFeature" into smaller pieces and export those smaller pieces as named exports.