# When I try to export action with redux I get an error that says "does not contain a default export"

Tags: reactjs, redux, import, export

I am trying to learn redux and I have a file with an action in it.

```
export const changeTitle = () => {
  return {
    type: 'CHANGE_PROJECT_TITLE',
  };
};
```

Then I am trying to import it in a component.

```
import changeTitle from '../actions/index.js';
```

This works if I use export default in the action file but then I can only have one action.

```
export default changeTitle;
```

I am trying to figure out why it will not work without the the export default. 
When I try without the export default I get an error that says : "Attempted import error: '../actions/index.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'changeTitle')." I believe I have seen examples that work without the default export so they can use multiple actions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and when to use default export over named exports in es6 Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913851/why-and-when-to-use-default-export-over-named-exports-in-es6-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case just change

`import changeTitle from '../actions/index.js';`

to

`import { changeTitle } from '../actions/index.js';`

and you can omit index.js name in import, it's default file for import

`import { changeTitle } from '../actions';`

more information about export you can find on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much! I also really appreciate the link where I can learn more.