# Is there a use case for exporting the same const as a named and default export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

## Question

I have seen a large codebase where every file with constants looks something like this:

```js
export const DEFAULT_ID = 0;
export const CURRENT_CODE = 'ABC123';

export default {
  DEFAULT_ID,
  CURRENT_CODE
};
```

They are using both a named as well as a default export for all constants. When it comes to how the constants are actually being imported, it seems that they are usually simply importing them as named exports:

```js
import {CURRENT_CODE} from './whatever.consts';
```

**Is there any use case for this practice?** It’s unusual, since, normally, either a named or a default export is used, not both.

## Research

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913851/why-and-when-to-use-default-export-over-named-exports-in-es6-modules) hoping to get some insight into why one would use them together in this manner, but I couldn’t find anything.

The closest thing I got to an answer was in [this article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/default-exports-or-named-exports-why-not-both/). In the section “*Why expose a symbol as both default and named exports*?”, they provide a brief example of how this allows someone to use `import {A, B} from './a'` instead of needing to write something like `import A, {B} from './a'`. However, this explanation doesn’t make sense to me since the same syntax can be used if the constants are simply exported as named exports.

## My Thoughts

The only reason I can think of is that this approach can give more flexibility when it comes to importing constants. I.e., it allows using both

```js
import {DEFAULT_ID, CURRENT_CODE} from './whatever.consts';

let id = DEFAULT_ID, code = CURRENT_CODE;
```

and

```js
import INITIALIZATION_CONSTS from './whatever.consts';

let id = INITIALIZATION_CONSTS.DEFAULT_ID, code = INITIALIZATION_CONSTS.CURRENT_CODE
```

for importing the constants.

Is this a valid reason for using this approach? Are there any best practices implications?

Comment: What code base in particular? Did you ask the author(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any use case for this practice?

Not really. The only thing I can think of is backwards-compatibility, possibly related to how they are transpiling their code, if the module is a library used elsewhere.

> The only reason I can think of is that this approach can give more flexibility when it comes to importing constants.

A default export is not necessary for that. You can easily use a namespace import with named exports only:

```
import * as INITIALIZATION_CONSTS from './whatever.consts';

let id = INITIALIZATION_CONSTS.DEFAULT_ID, code = INITIALIZATION_CONSTS.CURRENT_CODE
```