# import error: 'Header' is not exported from 'components/Header'

Tags: reactjs

I have my components folder with a component named Header. the Main JS file and Styles file. For some reason I am getting **`"import error: 'Header' is not exported from 'components/Header'"`**

Header.js:

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>The Header</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Components/Header/index.js:

```
export * from "./Header";
```

App.js:

```
import { Header } from "components/Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you do a default-export (`export default Header`) so you'll have to import it this way:

```
import Header from "components/Header"
```

If you want to use a named import (import { Header } from "components/Heaader";) you'll have to leave the "deafault" away from your export.

This StackOverflow post explains the difference well:
[Why and when to use default export over named exports in es6 Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913851/why-and-when-to-use-default-export-over-named-exports-in-es6-modules)

Comment: Now i get this: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Doing this: export { default } from "./Header";
 works.

Answer (score 0):

I just did copied the path by right clicking the file and selecting copy the path
and did

import Header from "/Users/********/Downloads/keeper-app-part-1-starting/src/components/Header.jsx";

and it worked