# how to use react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm trying to add a datepicker using `react-datepicker` but when I tried it in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-rain-11xoj4?file=/src/App.js), I got this error message:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

even though I already put `import { DatePicker } from "react-datepicker";` and add the `react-datepicker` package in the dependency list.

here's my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "react-datepicker";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and when to use default export over named exports in es6 Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913851/why-and-when-to-use-default-export-over-named-exports-in-es6-modules)

Answer (score 0):

In Line 2, change to: `import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";`

That should resolve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. In this one, we select a month from datepicker.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(null);
  
  const onDateChangeHandler = useCallback(date => setDate(date), [date]);

  return (
    <div className="position-relative">
      <DatePicker
        className="form-control w-100 text-center"
        placeholderText="Select date"
        selected={date}
        onChange={onDateChangeHandler}
        dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
        showMonthYearPicker
        showFullMonthYearPicker
        showTwoColumnMonthYearPicker
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Further reading

[React DatePicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes in code try this it should work.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```