# Imports causing methods to not be called in JS

Tags: javascript, html, importerror

When I use an import statement to import a method from a JS file it causes the rest of the methods in the file to not be called.Both files are in same directory

This is my searchBar.js file which has a searchbar component and a method that is called to create that component. However, when I have the import statement the create search bar method is never called.

```
import {addStops} from "./map.js";

function createSearchBar() {
    console.log("method called")
    const searchBar = document.createElement('input');
    searchBar.setAttribute('id', 'lineSearchBar');
    searchBar.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    searchBar.setAttribute('name', 'search');
    searchBar.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search a Bus Line');
    searchBar.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';
    searchBar.style.fontSize = '16px';
    searchBar.style.padding = '10px';
    searchBar.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    searchBar.style.borderRadius = '5px';
    searchBar.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    searchBar.style.width = '25%';
    searchBar.style.margin = '10px';
    searchBar.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    searchBar.style.position = 'relative'; // Set position to relative
    document.body.appendChild(searchBar);

    const suggestionsContainer = document.createElement('div');
    suggestionsContainer.setAttribute('id', 'suggestionsContainer');
    suggestionsContainer.style.position = 'absolute'; // Position suggestions container absolutely
    suggestionsContainer.style.top = 'calc(100% + 5px)';
    suggestionsContainer.style.left = '0';
    suggestionsContainer.style.width = '100%';
    suggestionsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    suggestionsContainer.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    suggestionsContainer.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    searchBar.parentNode.appendChild(suggestionsContainer); // Append suggestions container to searchBar's parent

    searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        const searchTerm = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const suggestionsContainer = document.getElementById('suggestionsContainer');

        suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        const matchingRoutes = Object.keys(shortNameBusLines).filter(route => route.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
        matchingRoutes.forEach(route => {
            const suggestion = document.createElement('div');
            suggestion.textContent = route;
            suggestion.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            suggestion.style.padding = '5px';
            suggestion.style.borderBottom = '1px solid #ccc';
            suggestion.addEventListener('click', function() {
                searchBar.value = route;
                suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = '';
                makeLineRequest(searchBar.value);
            });
            suggestionsContainer.appendChild(suggestion);
        });
    });
}

createSearchBar();
```

Here is the method from (map.js) that has the method I am importing :

```
export default function addStops(stops) {
    for (const key in stops) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const coords = dict[key];
            const lat = parseFloat(coords[0]);
            const lon = parseFloat(coords[1]);
            const iconUrl = '8405421.png';
            const iconSize = [10, 10];
            const customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: iconUrl,
                iconSize: iconSize
            });
            const marker = L.marker([lat, lon], { icon: customIcon }).addTo(map);
            marker.bindPopup(key);
    
            marker.on('click',function(){
                displayInfo(key);
            });
    
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="map.js"></script>
   <script type="module" src="searchbar.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    


</head>

<body>
   

   <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 580px; margin-top: 50px;"></div>

   <button id="stopsButton">Show Stops</button>


</body>

</html>
```

I am not recieving any console errors related to these methods.If someone can let me know why the imports cause the method to not be called that would be a great help.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: The only reasons adding an `import` to code that otherwise runs are A) You're doing it in something that isn't a module (but yours seem to be), or B) There's an error in the import.

Comment: Finally, if `searchBar.js` imports from `map.js`, there's no need to have a `script` tag for `map.js`. The browser will load it because of the import. I suggest stepping back from your current task and reading up on modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Should be `import addStops from "./map.js";`

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code.

### 1. Files on the web are case-sensitive

You load the file `searchbar.js`, but your file is called `searchBar.js`. Small/Big letters might not be important on a Windows PC, but they are important on the web.

### 2. You are loading a named export, but you want the default

When things aren't working as expected, the first thing you want to do is to check the console. You'll see this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './map.js' does not provide an export named 'addStops' (at searchBar.js:1:10)
```

This is because when you use the curly braces in `import {addStops} from "./map.js";` it expects the file to have a *named export*, but you have a *default export* `export default function addStops(stops)`. [This question goes deeper on the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913851/why-and-when-to-use-default-export-over-named-exports-in-es6-modules)

This is an easy fix. Either you change that line to

`export function addStops(stops)`

...or you change the import to

`import addStops from "./map.js";` (without the curly braces).

Comment: Also, `<script type="module" src="map.js"></script>` should be removed, otherwise it will be loaded twice

Comment: @Konrad Indeed, that import serves no purpose. It won't load twice though, as ES modules are only evaluated once.