# Vue import failing

Tags: import, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I've created a vue application scaffolded from the vue cli.  Almost everything is reacting as expected with my app except for an issue with import.

The following works fine:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
```

but, this throws errors:

```
import { VuetronVue, VuetronVuex } from 'vuetron';
vue.use(VuetronVue);
```

Linting error:

> "export 'VuetronVue' was not found in 'vuetron'

and Console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Changing the code to:

```
import vuetron from 'vuetron'
vue.use(vuetron.VuetronVue);
```

resolves the issue...

This original code was taken directly from the Vuetron documentation. Does anyone have a suggestion as to why the ES6 notation would cause an issue?

Comment: Did you install the vuetron?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281. I believe this will help you

Comment: Lara Belle - yes, I did. Both the npm install and the standalone app. I followed the instructions from the docs and it works if I use the second method.

@cuongngo - thank you. At first blush the info in there makes sense and matches my understanding of when to use curly braces on an import. I will have to dig into the vuetron source to see if the pieces are set for export or not. I was simply copying the example from the docs at the time.

Also wondering if I have something in my config set up improperly that would result in vuetron ES6 imports not working since the ES5 approach works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because

```
vuetron/packages/vuetron-plugins/index.js
```

only exports the default object:

```
import VuetronVue from './vuetron-vue';
import VuetronVuex from './vuetron-vuex';

export default {
  VuetronVue,
  VuetronVuex
};
```

For named imports as stated in the docs you would need a named export.