# React.createElement expected string problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was just learning React fundamentals and then I got this problem:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `App`.

I looked at everything and I don't know if I got something wrong there because I can't see any errors at all.
Saw some problems like this but couldn't solve my own one :D
here is some code

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import MainContent from "./components/MainContent";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <MainContent />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}


export default App
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav>This is a Navbar</nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

MainContent.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function MainContent() {
    return (
        <main>This is a footer</main>
    )
}

export default MainContent
```

Footer.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>This is a footer</footer>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551468 it doesn’t seem like you have problems from what you shared but maybe there are things we can’t see that are making problems.

Comment: @Rajesh It is HTML5 tags

Comment: I'm guessing it's the mixed case in your import vs filename for `app`.

Comment: I created a react project with your code, It's working fine.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-noyce-3g4r8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't know I'll check that, but don't think so.

Comment: Just try to clean the build or install npm packages again.

Answer (score 0):

is it because you're importing from the file `App.js` (capitalized) but the file is called `app.js` (no caps) ?

Comment: If this is the issue, we should put a comment and mark it as a Typographical question. Your point maybe valid but is does not answer anything. Its more of a comment at this point of time

Comment: It seems very unlikely since the error says "check the render method of App". That would make it seem like `App` is imported and used correctly, but one of it's children is not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27648558)

Comment: @BrianThompson yeah I thought that as well, but it wouldn't surprise me if this was indeed the issue--my original suggestion was to rebuild everything, maybe something got stuck while code changes were being made

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I believe this could be the answer, so I'm sticking to my guns here.

Comment: The OP's code works in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bush-qkbi8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

(minus changing MainContent render text content to match), so I agree with the answer that this is a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the issue: but have you tried changing `<footer>`, `<nav>`, and `<main>` to just `<div>`?

Comment: Those are just basic HTML Tags.

Comment: No I didn't, Well I don't think that we'll be a problem but I'll try