# Invalid Element Type with reactJS and google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am currently encountering this error while using reactJS with [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react). I followed the example from [here](https://jsbin.com/roqutisoqu/1/edit?js,console,output)

The error is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `MyComponent`

Below is the content of `MyComponent.tsx`.

Import statement:

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
```

States for the map

```
state = {
        center: [ 49.872768, 8.651180 ],
        zoom: 14
    };
```

and the render() method

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>WorldMap</div>

                <div style={{ width:"100%", height: 400 }}>
                    <GoogleMapReact center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
                    </GoogleMapReact>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
```

It is the bare minimum of the required stuff for showing google map, but I can't seem to find out where the error is

Any help is appreciated. Thanks before

**EDIT**
I forgot to add a bit more details. I am using requireJS for getting reference to the module. Below is the config

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './out',
    paths: {...,
        'google-map-react': '../node_modules/google-map-react/dist/GoogleMapReact.min'
    }
});
```

I checked the path and it points to the correct js file (GoogleMapReact.min.js).

Strangely, in my .tsx file, I encountered a semantic error (Visual Studio Code) which states that it cannot find the module 'google-map-react' from the import above

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'google-map-react'

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are Importing GoogleMapReact wrongly. This was the case for me atleast.
Try:

```
 import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
```

instead of

```
 import {GoogleMapReact} from 'google-map-react';
```

Because of this its not able to recognize GoogleMapReact as a component.

Comment: Have removed the curly brackets. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Importing without brackets works if what you are importing is the default export from where it is exported, importing with brackets imports a named export. In your case GoogleMapsReact is the default export from where it is exported and therefore should be imported without brackets.  see related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/5718714

another thing you can try is to change 
  `from 'google-map-react';` to `'from 'google-maps-react';` as the package name seems to be google-maps-react.

assuming the package you are using is https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react. I had no problem using your code, with the slight modification that i am using a local variable for state in render() instead of state. This example is based off of the create-react-app project.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';


class App extends Component {
    render() {
       let state = {
        center: [ 49.872768, 8.651180 ],
        zoom: 14
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
            <p className="App-intro">
               To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <div>
                <div>WorldMap</div>

                <div style={{ width:"100%", height: 400 }}>
                    <GoogleMapReact center={state.center} zoom={state.zoom}>
                </GoogleMapReact>
                </div>

            </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Looking at the docs for require js http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html, it states that `paths`should not point to a single js file but rather a dir, maybe try with the dist folder under google-map-react ?

from docs:

```
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'],
function   ($,        canvas,   sub) {
    //jQuery, canvas and the app/sub module are all
    //loaded and can be used here now.
});
```

Comment: That was what I have tried also. Still does not work (same error)

Comment: nope. Have checked and tested it with 'google-maps-react', but it threw missing js file error. I am sure the module name is 'google-map-react'

Comment: There is always two of everything on npm :), well i tried the module i think you are using and it renders fine. see above

Comment: I have added more details to my question