# GraphQL-Tools On SchemaError

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm probably making a rookie mistake somewhere, but why is the console telling me to provide a typeDefs? When I am providing one by using export default in javascript from the file below. I tried re-installing the package and such, but I get the same error still.

schema.js :

```
export default `
    type Query {
        hi: String
    }
`;
```

Then a screenshot of my app.js and the error:
[image]

I also tried this way of defining and exporting, and still get "Must provide typeDefs", and this was in the tutorial, schema.js:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Query {
        hi: String
    }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a default export in your type definitions, but trying to import a named export in `app.js`. Instead, the import should look like this:

```
import typeDefs from './server/schemas/schema'
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think it was part of es6 syntax that way, but I searched and found this that helped my understanding of your answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281

Thank you again.