# How can i resolve this error in React+Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, material-ui

I'm getting the following error while tried to `webpack` the application in windows 10 x64 b.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/material-ui/styles/withStyles.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/map'
```

I searched on the `github` and `stackoverflow`but don't find proper answer.

my Material UI  is `"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",`.
and `"@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",`.

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252876/how-can-i-resolve-this-error-in-reactmaterial-ui) and try that solutions.
1-`npm install @babel/runtime`
2-`npm install @material-ui/core`
but I also have the error.
How can i resolve this?

Comment: I remove ```babel/runtime``` and install older version ```7.0.0``` but it isn't correct answer.

Comment: I use ```npm update``` all package but not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my answer https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9026

The `material-ui` beta package is ***deprecated*** and buggy, hence the issue here. You should change to a stable version of `@material-ui/core`.