# Importing javascript modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I wrote a Javascript module called module.js that does the following

```
export default function myModule() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do a bunch of stuff
    });
};
```

I have the following Javascript code, test.js, that uses myModule() in module.js

```
import {myModule} from "module";
myModule().then((retVal) => {
    console.log(retVal);
});
```

Unfortunately, my browser console is telling me I have the following syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The console says the syntax error on line 1 of test.js but I can't see what's wrong with it. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: What is "test.js"?

Comment: Are you setting `babel` or `webpack` properly? maybe you browser doesn't know `import`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only importing a single function, you should remove the `{}` from the import. Also, you should change from, to a "path syntax".
You should end up with this:

```
import myModule from "./module";
```

Answer (score 1):

When exporting with `default` you don't use the braces `. Try this instead:

`import myModule from "module"`

See here: [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281)

### Edit

As mentioned, if you are importing this from a file in your project rather than a node module then you will to specify the path to the file you are exporting from. I have tested the below code in my project and do receive the expected result `test resolve` in the console. Let me know if this still doesn't work for you.

**module.js**

```
export default function myModule() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do a bunch of stuff
        resolve('test resolve');
    });
};
```

**index.js**

```
import myModule from "./module"; // Notice there are no braces (as we are exporting default) and that we are specifying the path
myModule().then((retVal) => {
    console.log(retVal);
});
```

**Specifying the path**

`./` will search in the current directory of the file you are importing with.

`../` will search the directory one level up from the file you are importing with

`../../` will search the directory two levels up from the file you are importing with

Comment: Now I'm getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: and again, the source of the error is line 1 of test.js

Comment: test.js is the second code chunk in my original post

Comment: And that is what I was asking you to change. Also note that you need to use path syntax as mentioned by MBehemam, I didn't include this in case may have been importing directly from a node module. See the updated code with `./` in the import path.

Answer (score 0):

This is about importing a JavaScript module in browser JavaScript.

If test.js is in the same directory as your file, `./module` is used; else, you might have `../module` or `../src/module` or some other path to `module.js` from current directory of `test.js`.  Has to be a comolete path, the `./` and `../` chaining is preferred.  If you have a tests directory, say your test.js is in `tests/test.js` you are importing `../module.js` if it is in root, or `../src/module.js` if it is in `src/module.js`.

Assuming `test.js` is in the same directory as `index.html` and `module.js`, in `test.js` you can use:

```
import myModule from "./module";
```

This way in HTML, `index.html` you should have:

```
<HTML>
<HEADER>

<script src='./test.js'>
// inside the script you would need to fix your import paths.
</script>

</HEADER>
<body>
</body>
</HTML>
```

The keyword here is browser, question asks about `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in browser, means import is unexpected.

Node.JS with Gatsby.JS, Next.JS or Vue.JS might work your way, package.json might need or might have an entry if your module installs into node_modules.