# When do we use '{ }' in javascript imports?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I am learning Javascript imports and I am yet to understand when we use  curly braces while importing items(functions, objects, variables) from another JS file.

```
import Search from './models/Search';
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base'
//elements is an object, renderLoader is a function
```

Comment: depends on what is being exported - your own question has 2 versions that do not use `{}` - so, your question is not clear at all - [here's some helpful documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: @JaromandaX I assume they added those 2 versions to show that often import is being used without `{}`.

Comment: I understand the versions where {} are not used. But , I don't know why {} should be used in the last case.

Comment: it depends on how many `exports` does the source object have if one or default then no need to use the `{}` else if the source object has multiple then you can specify `{}` and just select the ones that you want to use.

Comment: what's important is the export - import and export work hand in hand, without understanding the export, you won't understand the import

Comment: The symbols you import may or may not have an impact on the total bundled size of your application (when using a bundler). See [_"tree shaking"_](http://2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html). [In the past](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2713), `import *` made it difficult to isolate used and unused parts of code but these days, I believe it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Wow, so many answers of varying quality - almost none give the whole story - read the manual

Comment: I read all the answers and then read then the documentation at MDN. I understand it now, thanks. I am sorry I can't up-vote the answers, I don't have the privilege to up-vote yet.

Comment: @Bony you've got 15 rep, you should be able to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: The answer you have approved is not correct. Please re-check and verify.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Your comment about the approved answer being incorrect is no longer true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base'
```

is the way you need to import single, named exports from a module, in this case it is importing *named exports* `elements` and `renderLoader` from `base.js`.

The `{ elements, renderLoader }` syntax is in many cases just syntactic sugar (called *destructuring*) added in recent versions of the ECMAScript standard.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

**In this case, though, it is necessary to get only the named exports you want.**

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module

Please note that you can also pick **new names** for your variables like this:

```
import { elements as newNameForElements, renderLoader as newNameForRenderLoader } from './views/base'
```

which would then make the `elements` export available as `newNameForElements` etc.

Comment: This is totally incorrect! `import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base'` is not the same as doing `import elements from './views/base'; import renderLoader from './views/base'`. If you haven't default exported `elements` or `renderLoader` then both the variables would be `undefined` in the second case. You have to pick them up using currly braces for proper import like so: `import {elements} from './views/base'; import {renderLoader} from './views/base'`.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Thanks for the heads up. Your are totally correct and I tried to delete my answer (which wasn't possible since it was the accepted answer), so I have corrected my answer accordingly. Please re-check and reconsider your downvote.

Comment: I did :) Mind my answer for more clarifications on export and imports in ES6.

Answer (score 15):

The import statements are used to import the exported bindings from another module

The curly braces ({}) are used to import named bindings and the concept behind it is called destructuring assignment The concept of destructuring assignment is a process that makes it possible to unpack the values from arrays or objects into distinct variables in the imported module

**The curly braces ({}) are used to import named bindings**

I would like to explain different types of imports in ES6 with the help of an example

Suppose we have a module named Animals(Animals.js) let suppose the module exports a default binding `Man` and several other named bindings such as `Cat`, `Dog` etc

```
/*
 Animals.js
*/
..
export Cat;
export Dog
export default Man
```

**Import a single export from a module**

In order to export a single export from another module (let's say Cat) we can write it like this

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import {Cat} from "./Animals"
```

Similarly for Dog

```
/*
 YetAnothermodule.js
*/
import {Dog} from "./Animals"
```

**Import multiple exports from module**

You can also import multiple modules as follows

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import {Dog, Cat} from "./Animals"
```

**Import an export with a more convenient alias**

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import {Dog as Puppy}  from './Animals.js';
```

**Rename multiple exports during import**

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import {Dog as Puppy, Cat as Kitty}  from './Animals.js';
```

But in the case to import Man into another module since it is a default export you can write it like this

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import Man  from './Animals.js';
```

You can also mix both the above variants for example

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import Man, {Dog as Puppy, Cat as Kitty} from '/Animals.js';
```

**Import an entire module's contents**

If you want to import everything you can use

```
/*
 Anothermodule.js
*/
import * as Animals from './Animals.js';
```

Here, accessing the exports means using the module name ("Animals" in this case) as a namespace. For example, if you want to use Cat in this case you can use it like below

```
Animals.Cat
```

You can read more information about import [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

you can read about destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Great answer. Also, you can use an alias for `Man`, such as: `import SuperMan from 'Animals.js'`

Comment: Named imports are **not destructuring assignments**. Were it destructuring, renaming the import wouldn't be done using `as` but using `import { module: myModuleName } from ...`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Search from './models/Search';
```

Imports the **default exported element** as `Search`.

```
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
```

Imports **everything** into `searchView` that has been exported.

```
import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base'
```

Imports **a hand-picked number of named exported elements**.

Answer (score 2):

{} is used when you want to import part of an object. The * as searchView one will import all properties and methods in the searchView file.

Suppose './views/base' has 3 properties: elements, renderLoader, additionalParam (Assuming that all three have been exported as named exports in the file)

When doing

```
import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base'
```

you import only those 2 specific properties

But when you do

```
import * as base from './views/base'
```

you import all three properties in the object named base

Answer (score 1):

Take the following example:

File to be imported, say **importedFile.js**:

```
var defaultExport, otherExport1, otherExport2, otherExport3;

export default defaultExport = () => {
    console.log("Default Export")
}

export otherExport1 = "Other non-default Export";

export otherExport2 = function() {
  console.log("Some more non-default Export");
};

export otherExport3 = { msg: "again non-default Export" };
```

Now in your main JS file, if you would do the following:

```
import something from './importedFile.js;
```

Here the variable `something` would get the value of the variable/function that has been exported as default in the *importedFile.js* file, i.e. the variable `defaultExport`. Now, if you do something like the following:

```
import { otherExport1, otherExport2 } from './importedFile.js;
```

It would import specifically `otherExport1` and `otherExport2` variable and function and not the `defaultExport` and `otherExport3`.

You can also do something like the following to import all the variables by their names from *importedFile.js*:

```
import { defaultExport, otherExport1, otherExport2, otherExport3 } from './importedFile.js';
```

> Conclusion:
>
> 1. curly braces are used to choose variables/functions/objects (using a technique called *object destructuring* in ES6) that need to be imported without importing all the other unnecessary exported variables/functions/objects.
> 2. If you don't specify curly braces, it would always import only the variable/function/object that has been exported as default and nothing else. It would import *undefined* if nothing has been exported as default export.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly braces to import **implicitly** and selectively from another module functions or objects and so on.

```
// import implicitly one function and one constant from example.js
import { a, b } from 'example'
```

example.js

```
// export a and b but kept c private to example.js
export const a => { ... }
export const b = "hello"
const c = "private, not visible to the outside"
```

More infos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 0):

If something is exported as default it is imported without curly braces.

If multiple variables are exported it is imported using curly braces.

For example,

in somefunction.js

```
export default module;

import module from './somefunction.js';
```

in someOtherFunction.js

```
export func1;

export func2;

import { func1, func2 }  from './someOtherFunction.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export more than 1 content from a single module.

For example at your code:

```
import * as searchView from './views/searchView'; //1
import { elements, renderLoader } from './views/base' //2
```

At `//1`, you import **Everything** from `'./views/searchView';`

At `//2`, there might be more content from `'./views/base'`, but you import **only** `elements and renderLoader`

For more information: [import MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)