# export 'AddPlaceModal' was not found in '~/components/AddPlaceModal.vue'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just started using nuxt for vue. I added a component in the /components folder and I am trying to use it in one of my pages.

Unfortunately, I get this warning, upon compilation:

```
"export 'AddPlaceModal' was not found in '~/components/AddPlaceModal.vue'
```

I am trying to use it via:

```
<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex';
import {AddPlaceModal} from '~/components/AddPlaceModal.vue'; 

export default {
    components: {
        'add-place-modal': AddPlaceModal
    },
...
```

The component itself looks like:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        googleLocation: null;
    },
...
```

Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to import from default export, not a named export

```
import AddPlaceModal from '~/components/AddPlaceModal.vue';
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you.
If someone interested in what that curly-braces mean, open [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm used to angular so wasn't understanding why it was not working

Answer (score 14):

**you have to remove the curly brackets**

**do this:**

> [image: Blockquote]

**instead of:**

[image]