# How to export and import a directory of exported default files in Sanity schema?

Tags: import, directory, export, sanity

Most tutorials and docs I've read utilize a structure like this for the Sanity's *schema.js* file:

```
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'

import blog from './documents/blog'
import author from './documents/author'

export default createSchema({
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    blog,
    author,
  ]),
})
```

but I'd like to import the directory as a single source and I tried:

schema.js:

```
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'

import * as documents from './documents/'

export default createSchema({
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    documents,
  ]),
})
```

/documents/index.js:

```
export { default as author } from './author'
export { default as blog } from './blog'
```

and I tried:

```
import author from './author'
import blog from './blog'

export { author, blog }
```

Bringing all the individual files in *schema.js* works but when I try to change the file structure to reference one file I get an error of:

> <unnamed_type_@_index_1>

from `http://localhost:3333/desk/`.

### Research

- [Problem while exporting a function from another file in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001500/problem-while-exporting-a-function-from-another-file-in-react)
- [What does "export default" do in JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426521/what-does-export-default-do-in-jsx)
- [Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)
- [does not contain a default export even after being correctly imported in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412196/does-not-contain-a-default-export-even-after-being-correctly-imported-in-react)
- [ES6 exporting/importing in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file)
- [React - cannot export multiple files from index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499741/react-cannot-export-multiple-files-from-index-js)
- [Export all files in `index.ts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448783/export-all-files-in-index-ts)

In Sanity how can I export all my files within a directory and import them as one line in Sanity's schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this, you'd only have to make one small change:

**/documents/index.js:**

```
export { default as author } from './author'
export { default as blog } from './blog
```

**schema.js:**

```
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'

import * as documents from './documents'

const allDocuments = Object.values(documents)

export default createSchema({
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    ...allDocuments,
  ]),
})
```