# Uncaught TypeError: _dist_js_bundle__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack-4

Hi can someone help me with this?

I'm trying to export a function and use the function in other javascript files.

lib.js

```
const test= () => {
  console.log("test");
}

export {test};
```

app.js

```
import test from './test';
test();
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      test:'./test.js',
      app: './app.js'
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist/js/"),
      filename: './dist/bundle.js'
  },
 };
```

Comment: It should be `import {test} from './test';` Because you export object `export {test};`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: When I changed to `import {test} from './test';`. I got `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`