# How am I exporting my object incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'd like to know how I'm exporting my object incorrectly?  In my view, I'm seeing this error: `./src/context.js
Attempted import error: 'detailProduct' is not exported from './data'.`

In the console I indeed see the objects being populated correctly but for some reason it won't render my view because of the aforementioned error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
export const storeProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Crusk Beanie (black)",
    img: "img/CruskipBlackBeanie.png",
    price: 1,
    company: "Cruskip",
    info:
        "Winter's right around the corner, get your beanie today!",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Cruskip Short Sleeve T-shirt",
    img: "img/CruskipWhiteShortSleeve.jpg",
    price: 8,
    company: "Cruskip",
    info:
        "Exclusive Cruskip white t-shirts!",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
];

let detailProduct = {};

storeProducts.forEach((arrayItem) => {
  detailProduct = {
    id: arrayItem.id,
    title: arrayItem.title,
    img: arrayItem.img,
    price: arrayItem.price,
    company: arrayItem.company,
    info: arrayItem.info,
    inCart: arrayItem.inCart,
    count: arrayItem.count,
    total: arrayItem.total
  };
  console.log(arrayItem);
});

export default detailProduct;
```

Comment: Please post the code that tries to import from this module.

Comment: You will probably want to use `export const detailProduct = {};` instead of `let detailProduct = {};`, and drop the default export.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53521063/10349960 . Are you using the syntax correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely importing it using braces, but you can't do that for `default` exports:

```
// This will work
import detailProduct from './data';

// This won't
import { detailProduct } from '.data';
```

On the other hand, since `storeProducts` is a named export, it works the other way around:

```
// This will work
import { storeProducts } from './data';
// This won't
import storeProducts from './data';
```

Comment: Wow... this is all it was.  I was literally on the brink of insanity for 2 hours.  Thanks, Nick.

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Happy coding