# re-export es6 class module not working if use as class extender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have 5 js files,

I have exported a new component from `bar.js` with the name `NewComponent`
then on `route.js` I re-export with the same name `NewComponent`,
on `other.js` `NewComponent` works fine,
but in `dummy.js` `NewComponent` is not defined,
whereas if imported directly from `bar.js` `NewComponent` can run normally (see `sample.js`),
Is there a mistake I made?

```
/* bar.js */
import { Component } from 'react'
export default class NewComponent extends Component { }


/* route.js */
export { default as NewComponent } from './bar'

/* other.js */
import { NewComponent } from './route'
export default class Other extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NewComponent /> /* work */
    )
  }
}

/* dummy.js */
import { NewComponent } from './route'
export default class Dummy extends NewComponent { } /* undefined is not an object (evaluating '_bar.default') */


/* sample.js */
import NewComponent from './bar'
export default class Sample extends NewComponent { } /* work */
```

- UPDATE 
  here is my sample code
  https://codesandbox.io/s/km5n6o757v

Comment: just read this answer by Dan Abramov  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/1826429 (when to use curly braces while importing)

Comment: Thank you @goldy, I have read the reference that you gave me, and I think I did not make a mistake with the rules described by Dan-Abramov, I need route.js to export all my files, and the export method that I use on route.js is not there is a problem, the error occurs only when the class is extended by another class

Answer (score 0):

You need to import like this (without curly braces around it `{...}`)

```
/* dummy.js */
import NewComponent from './route'; // this is import Other component
```

See in `other.js` you are exporting `Other` as default component and using `NewComponent` component inside `Other`, not exporting it like you did in `route.js`

---

Read more about default imports vs named imports here https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: thanks for your answer @abdullah, but the error still won't disappear, now I can't find the NewComponent variable if I use the method you are using, because on route.js there is no export default

Comment: I need route.js to re-export all my files, and the export method that I use on route.js is no problem, the error occurs only when the class is extended by another class