# Meteor.loginWithPassword not invoking callback

Tags: reactjs, meteor, authentication

I've been adding user account functionality into a Meteor + React App.

For the login, using Meteor.loginWithPassword, I'm getting no indication of any special exception or crash in the server log. Yet, the callback never gets invoked.

[The Login Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6C46.png)

Seen above "Login Requested" will post in the console.

But "Login Processed" never does, showing that the callback is never executed.

accounts-ui as well as accounts-passwords have been added to meteor.

Subscriptions still work, so I'm not sure what's causing this to fail.

I'd at least expect some exception to get thrown on the server side as well, but I'm getting no apparent information on what's happening. 
Here is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Input, Button } from 'react-onsenui'

class LoginPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          username: "",
          password: "",
        };
    }

    loginRequest(){
        console.log("Login Requested")
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password, function(error){
            console.log("Login Processed");
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form className="LoginPage">
                <p>
                <Input
                    value={this.state.username} float
                    onChange={(event) => { this.setState({username: event.target.value})} }
                    modifier='material'
                    placeholder='Username' />
                </p>
                <p>
                <Input
                    value={this.state.password} float
                    onChange={(event) => { this.setState({password: event.target.value})} }
                    modifier='material'
                    placeholder='Password' />
                </p>
                <Button onClick={this.loginRequest.bind(this)} modifier="large--cta">Login</Button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: 1. you don't need accounts-ui for meteor react app. It is only for blaze.

Comment: 2. So what happend if you call "loginRequets"? Nothing at all? Double check that you call it from the react code + try to call Meteor.loginWithPassword directly form developer console

Comment: You were right! Going through the developer console worked.

Therefore, it wasn't something I could call from react code. There's definitely a misunderstanding of how I'm understanding things. 

How would I know if I can call something from react code or not?

Comment: You should be able to call all js function form react code 
Maybe if you post you react code I can help you 
most common mistake is to call the function instead of passing i
Or you can try to replace your loginRequest function with other one and see if it is called

Comment: I posted the code above. What do you mean replacing loginRequest function with another? 

Do you mean a separate function outside of the class?

Comment: Update - I've tried different ways to call the function. What I am finding is that I get an error.


'TypeError: Meteor.loginWithPassword is not a function. (In 'Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password, this.loginResult.bind(this))', 'Meteor.loginWithPassword' is undefined)'

I'm not sure why that would happen, since this is client-side code, I am importing Meteor, and I have added the accounts-password package.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the difference is between default import/export and named import/export.
Here's an explanation: [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

The first (without brackets) would mean a default import.  The second is a named import, which is matching the exact name of the export.

This matches the line

```
api.export('Meteor');
```

Which can be found in the core Meteor package:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/meteor/package.js

There is also an explanation of module info on the Meteor docs:
https://docs.meteor.com/packages/modules.html#Basic-syntax

You may also be interested in this thread on the Meteor forums:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-you-know-the-name-to-import/26718

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally solved this problem. 
Every time I think I understand Javascript, it's clear I do not.

The problem stems from how I imported Meteor. 
I changed

import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'

to

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

I don't know why this is the case, so someone please explain so I don't make this error again.