# Why importing with curly brace causes issue?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281) regarding the difference between importing with/without curly braces.

In my case, I have a class:

```
class PathResolver extends Component {
//content
}
export default connect()(PathResolver);
```

If I use
`import { PathResolver } from '/path';`
rather than
`import PathResolver from '/path';`
It will complain: `Attempted import error: 'PathResolver' is not exported from '/path'.`

These two import statements should be the same when the class name is "PathResolver", but it seems that the importing statement with curly braces cannot find the connected "PathResolver", why?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it if you export the class as well.

```
export class PathResolver extends Component {
//content
}
```

As currently your component is wrapped around redux you will not be able to access it

Comment: You mean `export class PathResolver`? In that case, the one with curly braces (`import { PathResolver } from '/path';`) will have problems with redux-related feature, such as `this.props.dispatch() is not defined`. It seems it's importing the pure class rather than the connected class.

Comment: @PhoenixPan, It will export the pure component, not the redux based feature. It is basically done for unit testing. Can you please explain your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I hope to keep the store connection and exported the connected component...it seems that I can't use `import { PathResolver } from '/path'` for connected component, but I don't know why...

Comment: buddy it is a weird way of doing it but you can assign your connected component to a variable then do 2 exports

Comment: Haha, I should simply do `import PathResolver from '/path'` with `default` keyword in the component. Just curious is it possible to explicitly import the connected component :p    

`import { connect()(PathResolver) } from '/path';` is definitely wrong...

Comment: @PhoenixPan by 2 exports you can use it both way

export default PathResolver ;
export {
  PathResolver 
}

Comment: but not the connected PathResolver? Well, I think I will just stay with default export for connected components, doesn't make sense to really figure out a way to import them explicitly using curly braces...Thanks!