# Module has no exported member issue when use React.js and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying group all components into one file, and use the file among all locations. But when I try to import Components from the file, it says `Module has no exported member`

The following are my code

**UserActionButton.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
class UserActionButton extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>BUTTON HERE</div>;
    }
}
export default UserActionButton;
```

**AppComponents.tsx**:

```
import UserActionButton from './buttons/UserActionButton';
export default {
    UserActionButton
};
```

**Home.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    UserActionButton
} from '../../components/AppComponents';
class HomePage extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hi, I’m a Home page component!</h1>
            <UserActionButton></UserActionButton>
        </div>;
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

The error was reported in `Home.tsx` file, please guide me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to use export default then you can remove the curly braces in import of `UserActionButton` in `Home.tsx`. `AppComponents.tsx` is exporting an object, though, so you should `import AppComponents from '...AppComponents'` and then pull out `UserActionButton` into a local `const` before use in your jsx: `const UserActionButton = AppComponents.UserActionButton;`

Answer (score 0):

in `Home.tsx` remove curly braces around `UserActionButton` in import statement

```
import UserActionButton from '../../components/AppComponents';
```

you shouldn't put curly braces when exported it as default. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove default from here i.e **AppComponents.tsx:**

```
import UserActionButton from './buttons/UserActionButton';
export {
    UserActionButton
};
```