# Is there a difference between these two Material-UI import methods?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using material-ui, I've been following the docs and importing using the method below

```
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
```

however, I recently came across some code where the above would have instead been imported as

```
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from '@material-ui/core';
```

The second method of importing obviously looks much cleaner, so is there any reason the docs and most code you'll find online all import it the first way?

Comment: Probably for browser compatibility purposes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way you importing the whole package:

```js
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from '@material-ui/core';
```

However, you can import individual components on demand:

```js
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
```

If you using `VSCode`, you can check the import size using [Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) extension.

It's important to mention that there are plugins for importing components on demand like `babel-plugin-import`, in this way you import individual components under the scene.

Answer (score 6):

`material-ui` is a library with a lot of components. 
In the first case you have imported just those components that you need in your project:

```
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
```

---

In the second case

`import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from '@material-ui/core';`

you have imported all components, even those you don't need. This could greatly increase the size of a bundle with unused dead-code in case if your module bundler has no tree shaking functionality.

I recommend you to use `import {...} from '@material-ui/core'` only if you know that your module bundler has tree shaking and you switched on this functionality. Or you could use this case if you using almost all components from `@material-ui/core`.

You could react about tree shaking in webpack [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Comment: Even if your bundler has tree shaking, it probably won't be enabled in development mode.  I have found that importing each one individually saved a lot of build time in development mode.

Comment: I agree with @MattH: as it says in the [docs](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#:~:text=Development%20bundles%20can,top%2Dlevel%20API.): "Startup times can be approximately **6x slower** than without named imports from the top-level API." (development mode). So if you want to speed up your dev start up time, prefer `path imports` or use `babel-plugin-import` as described in the MUI docs.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the only 3 components will be included in a bundle because you import 3 files.
In the second case - you import the core library in a bundle and use only 3 components from it.
But bundle builder should remove unused components, so you should check your bundle with tools like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer to see if you import unused code or not.